# Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

How do I move my recent commits on `master` to a new branch, and reset master to before those commits were made? e.g. From this:

```
master A - B - C - D - E
```

To this:

```
newbranch     C - D - E
             /
master A - B
```

Comment: Note: I asked the opposite question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492536/git-point-branch-to-new-commit)

Comment: http://eddmann.com/posts/move-last-git-commit-to-new-or-existing-branch/ this one works

Comment: Were the comments here purged? I ask because during my bimonthly visit to this question, I always scroll by that comment.

Comment: Side-comment: The question is about a very simple case. Reading the answers and all the "don't do this because..." and "a better solution is..." and "warning with version n+..." just after the answers (possibly when it's too late), it seems to me even very simple operations have no straight solutions in git. A graphical version manager where you would just add a tag for the new branch without dealing with what seems to me obscure and archaic syntax would be such a relief. My kingdom and my gold badges to the first one who "forks" git and starts a new approach ;-) it's urgent.

Comment: @mins Perhaps TortoiseGit is one step nearer to what you're asking for. The beauty of Git is that you have full control at your fingertips, but this requires a deeper understanding and a need for the user to be comfortable using a command line interface. I've been using Git for some years now, yet I still rely upon making references to the documentation and/or stackoverflow when I need to do less frequent operations. I like operating with the git CLI (I use GitBash) as I can get things done quickly. However, I turn to TortoiseGit to resolve conflicts as I find this easier.

Comment: Be sure to read through the first ten answers (or so), as the best are not the most upvoted.

Comment: @mins shame we're not all using mercurial. it's git but intuitive.

Comment: @jtbr: [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186287/774575) agrees with you and sets the scene with perspicacity.

Answer (score 8375, accepted):

WARNING: You **need to store uncommitted edits** to your stash before doing this, using `git stash`. Once complete, you can retrieve the stashed uncommitted edits with `git stash pop`. [git reset hard command will remove all changes!](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard)

### Moving to an existing branch

If you want to move your commits to an **existing branch**, it will look like this:

```
git checkout existingbranch
git merge branchToMoveCommitFrom
git checkout branchToMoveCommitFrom
git reset --hard HEAD~3 # Go back 3 commits. You *will* lose uncommitted work.
git checkout existingbranch
```

### Moving to a new branch

**WARNING:** This method works because you are creating a new branch with the first command: `git branch newbranch`. If you want to move commits to an **existing branch** you need to merge your changes into the existing branch before executing `git reset --hard HEAD~3` (see ***Moving to an existing branch*** above). **If you don't merge your changes first, they will be lost.**

Unless there are other circumstances involved, this can be easily done by branching and rolling back.

```sh
# Note: Any changes not committed will be lost.
git branch newbranch      # Create a new branch, saving the desired commits
git checkout master       # checkout master, this is the place you want to go back
git reset --hard HEAD~3   # Move master back by 3 commits (Make sure you know how many commits you need to go back)
git checkout newbranch    # Go to the new branch that still has the desired commits
```

But do make sure how many commits to go back. Alternatively, you can instead of `HEAD~3`, simply provide the hash of the commit (or the reference like *origin/master*) you want to "revert back to" on the *master* (/current) branch, e.g:

```sh
git reset --hard a1b2c3d4
```

**Note:** You will **only** be "losing" commits from the master branch, but don't worry, you'll have those commits in newbranch! An easy way to check that, after completing the 4 step sequence of commands above, is by looking at `git log -n4` which will show the history of newbranch actually retained the 3 commits (and the reason is that newbranch was created at the time those changes were already commited on master!). They have only been removed from master, as `git reset` only affected the branch that was checked out at the time of its execution, i.e. master (see [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) description: *Reset **current** HEAD to the specified state*). `git status` however will not show any checkouts on the newbranch, which might be surprising at first but that is actually expected.

Lastly, [you may need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git#comment42808558_6796816) to force push your latest changes to main repo:

```sh
git push origin master --force
```

**WARNING:** With Git version 2.0 and later, if you later `git rebase` the new branch upon the original (`master`) branch, you may need an explicit `--no-fork-point` option during the rebase to avoid losing the carried-over commits.  Having `branch.autosetuprebase always` set makes this more likely.  See [John Mellor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463546/1256452) for details.

Comment: And in particular, *don't* try to go back further than the point where you last pushed commits to another repository from which somebody else might have pulled.

Comment: Wondering if you can explain WHY this works.

To me you're creating a new branch, removing 3 commits from the old branch you are still on, and then checking out the branch you made.

So how do the commits you removed magically show up in the new branch?

Comment: @Jonathan Dumaine: Because I created the new branch before removing the commits from the old branch. They're still there in the new branch.

Comment: I see. Branching makes of clone of the state it is currently in. For some reason I was under the assumption that those commits would not get cloned because they were not on a remote server (too much git-svn haha). Thank you.

Comment: branches in git are just markers which point to commits in history, there is nothing being cloned, created or deleted (except the markers)

Comment: But then how would you push this to another repository? I get rejected when I do `git push` after `git reset --hard HEAD~3`.

Comment: I'd change 'git reset --hard HEAD~3' into 'git reset --hard origin/master'. Then you don't have to know how many commits you are ahead of master. It will sync your local master with the master on your server.

Comment: Also note: Don't do this with uncommitted changes in your working copy! This just bit me! :(

Comment: To take some of the risk out of resetting master back to the wrong commit, this one sets the branch back more precisely. "git reset --hard 1a0c9b", where "1a0c9b" is the start of the commit hash you wish to get back to.

Comment: Is there any reason why Mazrick's comment hasn't been upvoted more? This sounds like a far more reliable method than counting the number of commits.

Comment: Why is `git reset --hard` recommended so often?  Why not `git checkout head~3 .` (Note the `.` or you'll end up on a headless branch)?  (of course `head~3` could be replaced with alternatives mentioned above).  Seems `checkout` is much safer since it won't destroy your history.  Did I miss something?

Comment: yes you did, most likely people accidentally committed to the wrong branch, they want to HARD remove those commits after putting them on another branch, the other branch will most likely eventually be merged in to the accidentally committed one, after review & testing

Comment: "If you don't merge your changes first, they will be lost." -- This isn't entirely true. The commits only become detached. Garbage Collection takes a very long time (Something like >1000 commits or so maybe 10000?) So you can still recover them. Either by remembering the SHAs or finding them with `git reflog` or `git fsck --lost-found`. [More info on lost commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html)

Comment: By very long time I mean 30 days, NOT >1000 commits.

Comment: Why would you do unnecessary checkouts and trash your worktree?  `git checkout -b newbranch; git branch -f master master~3` (or ...`origin/master`).

Comment: If I then went to the newbranch and did a `git rebase master` would the newbranch get that commit removed though? If I used `merge` instead of `rebase` would I avoid this?

Comment: If you want to push master branch then (or original branch your rolled back) use `git push --force origin master`. In case you don't type force git will reject push and will ask you to pull rolled back commits form remote.

Comment: This is what I used: `git push --force -u origin master` and then `git push -u origin newbranch`.

Comment: sykora maybe you want to check out the meta-discussion over there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298067/top-voted-answer-is-dangerous-hiding-safer-answer?cb=1 - maybe you want to extend your answer to reference the very neat version @aragaer gave below (very underrated contribution as I think)

Comment: I'd like to know how to do that with the new GitHub Desktop software, if possible. I know my way around the command line for some things, but git is way too complicated in a text-based environment. Now that an accessible, free, GUI-based official solution is available, I'd like to use that.

Comment: Thanks Worked for me very well, only then reset a git stash apply, I changed to the correct branch and apply git stash pop! with that I get my changes and where I corresponded!

Comment: After you're dun effin up `git push origin oldBranch --force`

Comment: **This answer causes commits to be lost:** next time you `git rebase`, the 3 commits will be silently discarded from `newbranch`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36463546/691281) for details and safer alternatives.

Comment: I tested the procedure with the new branch way. But this doesn't move the commit. as someone pointed out push --force is necessary and will require to re-attach the HEAD to the commit tail. wouldn't it? (sorry if I missed something from the huge amount of comments :) )

Comment: Following these instructions caused me to lose all the commits I was trying to move. Now I have to do the work all over again. Resetting the commits from master had the effect of changing the fork point of the branch, which had no commits of its own.

Comment: `git push --force -u origin` for both master and the new branch should be part of the answer

Comment: I followed these instructions and thought I'd lost all my changes, then changed to the new branch and they were there.  Kind of blew my mind for a moment until I realized why it worked.  I'm dumb.  Thanks.

Comment: worked for me only with creating a new branch. Moving to an existing branch wasn't possible

Comment: Thats not a good solution, because in the git history it is still visible that you merged from master...

Comment: I have used this post so many times because I often accidentally commit to a local master branch and can never remember how to do this. Wish I could upvote ten times. Thanks yet again for saving me...

Comment: Once you've removed the commits from `master` you can switch to the last branch using `git checkout -`

Comment: I rolled back @Rennex's changes, since `--keep` option keeps the changes in the moved commits as uncommited changes, which is not the desired effect. Instead it makes a lot of mess if you move multiple commits with many changes. If you want to keep uncommited changes, stash them before.

Comment: Use "git reset --soft" to keep the changes locally

Comment: after cherry-pick, one can use the interactive rebase and change `pick` to `drop` if you want to remove the commits from the original branch. especially useful if your commits are jumbled up and you only want to move some specific commits. You will have to force push though.

Comment: Incase you are doing this in an existing branch as I did: To be able to rebase head~3 or in IDE(e.g IntelliJ) "rebase to here" It's important NOT to take a pull from remote repo. If you do that, there would be commits from others into your own. I wonder what could be done in that case? Individual commit deletes?

Also, I assume OP did not push his changes. If that were done a reset would delete the commits that were already pulled by others, and break their code, wouldn't it? Any good resource to know what could be done if items had been already pushed?

Comment: This works because your making a copy newbranch (A,B,C,D,E), and you're going back in history on branch master (A,B)

Comment: Why do we need `git checkout master` ? When we do `git branch newbranch` we stay on master don't we?

Comment: The checkout master in the 'Moving to a new branch' is not required git branch creates a branch without moving to it.

Comment: If you want to move HEAD on master to its original head as per remote branch then you can use `git reset --hard origin/master` (`origin/master` instead of `HEAD~3`) to avoid any miscalculation of # of commits or a wrong commit hash.

Answer (score 1259):

For those wondering why it works (as I was at first):

You want to go back to C, and move D and E to the new branch.  Here's what it looks like at first:

```
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
        ↑
      master
```

After `git branch newBranch`:

```
    newBranch
        ↓
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
        ↑
      master
```

After `git reset --hard HEAD~2`:

```
    newBranch
        ↓
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
    ↑
  master
```

Since a branch is just a pointer, *master* pointed to the last commit.  When you made *newBranch*, you simply made a new pointer to the last commit.  Then using `git reset` you moved the *master* pointer back two commits.  But since you didn't move *newBranch*, it still points to the commit it originally did.

Comment: @Andrew Without --hard it leaves the changes in the working directory. In that case we can create a new branch and commmit those changes on the new branch. Would this approach remove the need of ensuring that others have not pulled your changes?

Comment: I also needed to do a `git push origin master --force` for the change to show up in main repository.

Comment: Probably a good idea to use `--force-with-lease` in case someone has already committed based on top of your old chain.

Comment: **This answer causes commits to be lost:** next time you `git rebase`, the 3 commits will be silently discarded from `newbranch`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36463546/691281) for details and safer alternatives.

Comment: @John, that's nonsense.  Rebasing without knowing what you're doing causes commits to be lost.  If you lost commits, I'm sorry for you, but this answer didn't lose your commits.  Note that `origin/master` doesn't appear in the above diagram.  If you pushed to `origin/master` and then made the changes above, sure, things would go funny.  But that's a "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" kind of problem.  And it's out of scope for what the original question asked.  I suggest you write your own question to explore your scenario instead of hijacking this one.

Comment: @Kyralessa: The question asked for `newbranch` to be based off their existing local branch (which happens to be called `master`), implying that it should track it as a local upstream. After splitting the 3 commits off into `newbranch`, if the existing local branch is later changed (e.g. new commits are added locally, or pulled in from origin/master), then `git rebase` is a correct and reasonable way to incorporate those changes from the existing local branch into `newbranch`. (Merging is a valid alternative, but leads to more complicated history).

Comment: @John, in your answer, you said "Don't do this!  `git branch -t newbranch`".  Go back and read the answers again.  *Nobody* suggested doing that.

Comment: @Kyralessa, sure, but if you look at the diagram in the question, it's clear that they want `newbranch` to be based off their existing local `master` branch. After performing the accepted answer, when the user gets around to running `git rebase` in `newbranch`, git will remind them that they forgot to set the upstream branch, so they'll run `git branch --set-upstream-to=master` then `git rebase` and have the same problem. They may as well use `git branch -t newbranch` in the first place.

Comment: @JohnMellor, you are correct that calling `git rebase` with no arguments enables the `--fork-point` option, which can cause commits to be lost.  In my opinion this is a defect in `git rebase`.  It has nothing to do with my answer above, though.  There are many circumstances in which `git rebase` with no arguments can cause trouble.  The moral of the story (unfortunately) is not to call `git rebase` without passing in a branch, even if that branch is already the upstream.  Git's usability has improved quite a lot in the past eight years or so, but this is one area wherre it could use more work.

Comment: My recommendation is to use a Git alias to define a good alternative to `git rebase` with no arguments.  I use `git reup`: `alias.reup=rebase @{u}`  This way `git rebase` always uses the upstream branch rather than this "fork-point" nonsense.

Answer (score 601):

## In General...

The method exposed by sykora is the best option in this case. But sometimes is not the easiest and it's not a general method. For a general method use *git cherry-pick*:

To achieve what OP wants, its a 2-step process:

## Step 1 - Note which commits from master you want on a `newbranch`

Execute

```
git checkout master
git log
```

Note the hashes of (say 3) commits you want on `newbranch`. Here I shall use:
C commit: `9aa1233`
D commit: `453ac3d`
E commit: `612ecb3`

> **Note:** You can use the first seven characters or
>   the whole commit hash

## Step 2 - Put them on the `newbranch`

```
git checkout newbranch
git cherry-pick 612ecb3
git cherry-pick 453ac3d
git cherry-pick 9aa1233
```

## OR (on Git 1.7.2+, use ranges)

```
git checkout newbranch
git cherry-pick 612ecb3~1..9aa1233
```

*git cherry-pick* applies those three commits to newbranch.

Comment: if the cherry picking is the last N commits then you can just move your master HEAD back w/ `git reset --hard HEAD~N`

Comment: This works very well if you accidentally commit the wrong, non-master branch, when you should have created a new feature branch.

Comment: The information on git cherry-pick is nice, but the commands in this post don't work. 1) the 'git checkout newbranch' should be 'git checkout -b newbranch' since newbranch doesn't already exist; 2) if you checkout newbranch from the existing master branch it ALREADY has those three commits included in it, so there's no use in picking them. At the end of the day to get what the OP wanted, you'll still have to do some form of reset --hard HEAD.

Comment: +1 for a useful approach in some situations. This is good if you only want to pull your own commits (which are interspersed with others) into a new branch.

Comment: It's better answer. This way you can move commits to any branch.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Error message, "nothing added to commit". Previous cherry-pick is now empty. Allow empty or continue.    In any case, it didn't seem to work, commits didn't get moved over.

Comment: I was not able to use the cherry-pick range, got "error: could not apply c682e4b..." on one of the commits, but when used cherry-pick on each commit one at a time, it worked fine (I had to do git cherry-pick --abort after the error). Commenting because I thought those would be equivalent. This is on git version 2.3.8 (Apple Git-58)

Comment: For the refs, you can usually use 3-5 hexits; however many it takes Git to uniquely identify the commit. Also, you can use `master~3..master` to refer to the last 3 commits on `master` instead of hashes.

Comment: @konpsych I believe the order is important. You want to do the oldest commits first.

Comment: This works great if you want to reply the commits ontop of a existing branch instead of creating a new one with the misplaced commits on. A situation I've sometimes gotten myself into when working on many features in parallel.

Comment: These failed for me, but doing them in the "right" order, ie. in the chronological order of commits, worked for me: `git cherry-pick 9aa1233 453ac3d 612ecb3`

Comment: I actually wanted to move commits to a branch that is actually many commits behind the current branch. This answer helps in that case.

Comment: Once you copy them with `cherry-pick`, what's the best way to remove them from their original branch? I did it via dropping the commits thru `git rebase -i` but wondering if there is a preferred way.

Comment: For anyone wondering about the syntax of that range definition, there's a `~1` after the SHA of the first commit in the range you want to pick, to indicate that you would like to start with _the parent_ of that commit. Don't worry, this still does what you expect it to, it just avoids an off-by-one error.

Comment: Great! I always knew this not until I was were I need to understand it. Great write up over here!

Answer (score 453):

### Most previous answers are dangerously wrong!

Do NOT do this:

```sh
git branch -t newbranch
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git checkout newbranch
```

As the next time you run `git rebase` (or `git pull --rebase`) those 3 commits would be silently discarded from `newbranch`! (see explanation below)

**Instead do this:**

```sh
git reset --keep HEAD~3
git checkout -t -b newbranch
git cherry-pick ..HEAD@{2}
```

- First it discards the 3 most recent commits (`--keep` is like `--hard`, but safer, as fails rather than throw away uncommitted changes).
- Then it forks off `newbranch`.
- Then it cherry-picks those 3 commits back onto `newbranch`. Since they're no longer referenced by a branch, it does that by using git's [reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html): `HEAD@{2}` is the commit that `HEAD` used to refer to 2 operations ago, i.e. before we 1. checked out `newbranch` and 2. used `git reset` to discard the 3 commits.

*Warning: the reflog is enabled by default, but if you've manually disabled it (e.g. by using a "bare" git repository), you won't be able to get the 3 commits back after running `git reset --keep HEAD~3`.*

An alternative that doesn't rely on the reflog is:

```sh
# newbranch will omit the 3 most recent commits.
git checkout -b newbranch HEAD~3
git branch --set-upstream-to=oldbranch
# Cherry-picks the extra commits from oldbranch.
git cherry-pick ..oldbranch
# Discards the 3 most recent commits from oldbranch.
git branch --force oldbranch oldbranch~3
```

(if you prefer you can write `@{-1}` - the previously checked out branch - instead of `oldbranch`).

---

### Technical explanation

Why would `git rebase` discard the 3 commits after the first example? It's because `git rebase` with no arguments enables the `--fork-point` option by default, which uses the local reflog to try to be robust against the upstream branch being force-pushed.

Suppose you branched off origin/master when it contained commits M1, M2, M3, then made three commits yourself:

```
M1--M2--M3  <-- origin/master
         \
          T1--T2--T3  <-- topic
```

but then someone rewrites history by force-pushing origin/master to remove M2:

```
M1--M3'  <-- origin/master
 \
  M2--M3--T1--T2--T3  <-- topic
```

Using your local reflog, `git rebase` can see that you forked from an earlier incarnation of the origin/master branch, and hence that the M2 and M3 commits are not really part of your topic branch. Hence it reasonably assumes that since M2 was removed from the upstream branch, you no longer want it in your topic branch either once the topic branch is rebased:

```
M1--M3'  <-- origin/master
     \
      T1'--T2'--T3'  <-- topic (rebased)
```

This behavior makes sense, and is generally the right thing to do when rebasing.

So the reason that the following commands fail:

```sh
git branch -t newbranch
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git checkout newbranch
```

is because they leave the reflog in the wrong state. Git sees `newbranch` as having forked off the upstream branch at a revision that includes the 3 commits, then the `reset --hard` rewrites the upstream's history to remove the commits, and so next time you run `git rebase` it discards them like any other commit that has been removed from the upstream.

But in this particular case we want those 3 commits to be considered as part of the topic branch. To achieve that, we need to fork off the upstream at the earlier revision that doesn't include the 3 commits. That's what my suggested solutions do, hence they both leave the reflog in the correct state.

For more details, see the definition of `--fork-point` in the [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and [git merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) docs.

Comment: I think I'd be more satisfied with this answer if you could demonstrate what the "wrong" state of reflog would be as opposed to the right state in this circumstance.

Comment: In your scenario, if I keep M2 and M3 in my topic branch and then try to merge my topic branch back into master, then don't I reintroduce the edits someone else tried to delete (i.e. M2)? It would seem that this is undesired behavior, no? To me it makes sense that if someone is going to re-write history, you will want your topic branch to track the new history so you don't un-re-write history when you merge.

Comment: This answer says "Do NOT do this!" above something that no one suggested doing.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it if I already did this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/1628584/2423194 and doing `git push --force` to delete the commits that I already moved to the new branch?

Comment: Most people don't rewrite published history, especially on `master`. So no, they are not dangerously wrong.

Comment: @Makoto, after performing the "Do NOT do this" steps `git reflog newbranch` will have a single entry `db8f2fe newbranch@{0}: branch: Created from oldbranch` where `db8f2fe` is the hash of _T3_, and more importantly `git reflog oldbranch` will list the exact hashes of T1, T2 and T3. Together, it's clear that commits T1,T2,T3 were already part of oldbranch when newbranch forked off from it, hence they will be unexpectedly removed from newbranch by the next `git rebase`. Hence also `git merge-base --fork-point newbranch oldbranch` will fail to find the fork-point (instead of printing M3's hash).

Comment: @Makoto, if instead you perform either of my alternative steps, `git reflog newbranch` will start with `4b242c2 newbranch@{3}: branch: Created from HEAD` where `4b242c2` is the hash of _M3_, followed by 3 entries for the cherry-picks. And `git reflog oldbranch` will list T1, T2 and T3, but they will have different hashes there than they do in newbranch, since they were copied to newbranch by cherry-picking (in particular, cherry-picking updates the timestamp - assuming it has been longer than a second since the commit was created - causing it to get a new hash even if it's a fast-forward).

Comment: @GordonBean, yes, it is good that `git rebase` removes M2 from your topic branch when M2 is removed by rewriting from origin/master. It just means you have to be careful in this particular case (splitting existing commits from a local branch onto a dependent local branch), since git can't distinguish the two cases.

Comment: @Kyralessa, the `-t` you are referring to in `git branch` happens implicitly if you have `git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always` set. Even if you don't, I [already explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git/36463546?noredirect=1#comment60571505_6796816) to you that the same problem occurs if you setup tracking after performing these commands, as the OP likely intends to do given their question.

Comment: @RockLee, yes, the general the way to fix such situations is to create a fresh branch (newbranch2) from a safe starting point then cherry-pick all the commits you want to keep (from badnewbranch to newbranch2). Cherry-picking will give the commits new hashes, so you'll be able to safely rebase newbranch2 (and can now delete badnewbranch).

Comment: @Walf, you misunderstood: _git rebase_ is designed to be robust against upstreams having their history rewritten. Unfortunately, the side-effects of that robustness affect everyone, even if neither they nor their upstream ever rewrite history.

Comment: Okay, I do prefer the `cherry-pick` method since it's impossible to lose the commits (always visible in `git log`). However, if history is never rewritten, how does this lost commit situation occur?

Comment: Note: to check which commits to include, you can use `git reflog` which gives the HEAD@{xxx} reference.

Comment: Considering that many folks have autosetuprebase always set, your warnings are quite wecome. Thanks John Mellor. @sykora and Kyralessa, I think its worth putting a note on the accepted answer about when it is dangerous (always if autosetuprebase is set in your .gitconfig, which many folks do!). There's at least one comment up above from Rock Lee who followed the accepted answer and appears to have been burned.

Comment: @Walf, history is rewritten in this case by `git reset --keep`. So you're rewriting history yourself in this example by dropping commits, and that's how they're "lost" when rebasing.

Comment: You can also use `--no-fork-point` when you run `git rebase`.

Comment: The danger that is being avoided here is that commits on `newbranch` will be lost in a rebase. If `newbranch` is merged into `oldbranch` before a rebase happens, is that still a danger?

Comment: I've tried this with to put a merge on another branch, but then the cherrypick doesn't choose the other commits in the merge (only the top one), at least I think so. It seems however that after the reset, I can just "git checkout <commit>" (with the commit obtained from the reflog), and then create a new branch from there. whhat do you think?

Comment: if you use the cherry-pick method, you need to then reset the remote & merge of newbranch. I don't know the git commands to do that, I find it easier to just edit `.git/config`

Comment: Too bad this isn't the accepted answer. I followed the steps in the accepted answer and lost 6 commits, just as you described!

Comment: Instead of using the relative revision format, just take the current HEAD revision e.g. `aaaaaa`, the new HEAD for master `bbbbbb`, and the revision after `bbbbbb`, e.g. `cccccc`, then do
`git reset --keep bbbbbb` ;
`git checkout -t -b newbranch` ;
`git cherry-pick cccccc..aaaaaa`

Comment: Your 'alternative that doesn't rely on the reflog' does not interoperate with `git push`: it gives errors no matter which branch I try to push to remote repo: either old or new. Thumbs down

Comment: @Eugene Gr. Philippov Same here, git kept telling me that I need to `git push` - which in turn tells me that everything is up to date already and consequently does nothing. Next, git tells me to `git push`, cycle repeats. I am sure it is named "git" for a reason. I had to use `git push origin` to coerce cooperation.

Comment: I had **only one commit** to move. Important for this case: Use `HEAD~1` in the first step, but keep `..HEAD@{2}` in the last step. Otherwise you get a **cherry-pick** failed error. (When I tried `..HEAD@{0}` or `..HEAD@{1}` before, I got the cherry-pick error and **I thought my commit is lost**.)
. . . . . . . . . . So use these steps: `git reset --keep HEAD~1` `git checkout -t -b newbranch` `git cherry-pick ..HEAD@{2}`

Comment: In the last step I needed to use quotes so instead of just ...HEAD@{2}, I wrapped it with "...HEAD@{2}"

Comment: This technique seemed to give me what I wanted, though I'm now left with the inability to push commits:
"fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch", and the instructions provided in the rest of the message to `git push . HEAD` don't seem to do anything.

Comment: Update – Here are the three additional steps I needed to add to the 3 provided above to get things back to normal (it's possible #2 can be skipped, not sure):

`git push origin HEAD`
`git branch --unset-upstream`
`git push --set-upstream origin NEWBRANCH`

Answer (score 405):

Yet another way to do this, using just 2 commands. Also keeps your current working tree intact.

```
git checkout -b newbranch # switch to a new branch
git branch -f master HEAD~3 # make master point to some older commit
```

**Old version** - before I learned about `git branch -f`

```
git checkout -b newbranch # switch to a new branch
git push . +HEAD~3:master # make master point to some older commit
```

Being able to `push` to `.` is a nice trick to know.

Comment: Current directory. I guess this would work only if you are in a top directory.

Comment: The local push is grin-inducing, but on reflection, how is it different to `git branch -f` here?

Comment: @GerardSexton `.` is current director. git can push to REMOTES or GIT URLs. `path to local directory` is supported Git URLs syntax. See the GIT URLS section in `git help clone`.

Comment: I don't know why this is not rated higher. Dead simple, and without the small but potential danger of git reset --hard.

Comment: @Godsmith My guess is people prefer three simple commands to two slightly more obscure commands.  Also, top voted answers get more upvotes by nature of being displayed first.

Comment: I agree with @Godsmith! Why isn't this rated higher? The part about forcing master to point to a former commit is definitely the best option I have seen in here. Thank you @aragaer

Comment: Great answer! You can also use `@~3` in place of `HEAD~3`.

Comment: Worked for me… But can one of you explain you prefer this to the `reset --hard` method? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't alter the working tree at all - whatever modifications you have made to your code stay untouched - you don't even have to commit anything.

Comment: I agree, very simple. And again as @Dženan said in previous answer don't forget to do `git push origin master --force` do save the changes remotely too.

Comment: Here is the link to git branch command https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch. And to clarify, with the command `git branch -f master HEAD~3`, it doesn't have to be `master`.

Comment: A small warning: `git branch -f master <something>` will reset the tracking information on the master branch. So if you had set the upstream of `master` to anything other than `origin/master`, that setting will now be lost.

Comment: +1 this perfectly worked for me after I additionally did `git push origin master --force` and `git push --set-upstream origin <newbranch>`

Comment: Worked great for me.  Did have to git push origin ___ --force - actually I was a develop branch and it worked great on there

Comment: git push --force is necessary to replicate at the repo

Comment: `+` in front of refspec works as `--force` for that refspec.

Comment: Anything that avoids a reset or a merge or a cherry pick seems like a winner, and I reckon this one's the winner. The only thing I'd say is use the commit's checksum tag ID rather than HEAD-3, to save trying to count back how many commits.

Answer (score 276):

## Much simpler solution using git stash

Here's a far simpler solution for commits to the wrong branch. Starting on branch `master` that has three mistaken commits:

```
git reset HEAD~3
git stash
git checkout newbranch
git stash pop
```

### When to use this?

- If your primary purpose is to roll back `master`
- You want to keep file changes
- You don't care about the messages on the mistaken commits
- You haven't pushed yet
- You want this to be easy to memorize
- You don't want complications like temporary/new branches, finding and copying commit hashes, and other headaches

### What this does, by line number

1. Undoes the last three commits (and their messages) to `master`, yet leaves all working files intact
2. Stashes away all the working file changes, making the `master` working tree exactly equal to the HEAD~3 state
3. Switches to an existing branch `newbranch`
4. Applies the stashed changes to your working directory and clears the stash

You can now use `git add` and `git commit` as you normally would. All new commits will be added to `newbranch`.

### What this doesn't do

- It doesn't leave random temporary branches cluttering your tree
- **It doesn't preserve the mistaken commit messages,** so you'll need to add a new commit message to this new commit
- Update! Use up-arrow to scroll through your command buffer to reapply the prior commit with its commit message (thanks @ARK)

#### Goals

The OP stated the goal was to "take master back to before those commits were made" without losing changes and this solution does that.

I do this at least once a week when I accidentally make new commits to `master` instead of `develop`. Usually I have only one commit to rollback in which case using `git reset HEAD^` on line 1 is a simpler way to rollback just one commit.

**Don't do this if you pushed master's changes upstream**

Someone else may have pulled those changes. If you are only rewriting your local master there's no impact when it's pushed upstream, but pushing a rewritten history to collaborators can cause headaches.

Comment: Thanks, am so glad I read past/through so much to get to here, cause it's a pretty common use case for me as well.  Are we so atypical?

Comment: I think we're totally typical and "oops I commited to master by mistake" is the most common use-case for need to revert a handful or less of commits. Lucky this solution is so simple I have it memorized now.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's straightforward, easy to understand and easy to remember

Comment: It can be a solution but it does not do exactly what was asked because it loses the last 3 commits.

Comment: OP did not specific the commit messages had to be preserved. No code is lost.

Comment: I don't event think the stashing is necessary. I just did it without and worked well.

Comment: You can easily get your commit messages back, too, if you happen have them in your CLI (command line) history. I happened to have both the `git add` and `git commit` commands that I used so all I had to do was hit up arrow and enter a few times and boom! Everything was back, but on the right branch now.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly for me, because I only want to move the last commit, without the previous commits, to the other branch. Basically I made the mistake of committing to master instead of develop and master is ahead of develop with changes that I am not interested in merge right now.

Comment: To keep the commit messages too, you can just to git log before and copy them to a text file. Then later add all of that to the new message :)

Comment: If "newbranch" didn't exist yet, then you can move the unstaged changes after reset to a new branch with this command w/o having to stash: `git checkout -b newbranch`

Answer (score 34):

This doesn't "move" them in the technical sense but it has the same effect:

```
A--B--C  (branch-foo)
 \    ^-- I wanted them here!
  \
   D--E--F--G  (branch-bar)
      ^--^--^-- Opps wrong branch!

While on branch-bar:
$ git reset --hard D # remember the SHAs for E, F, G (or E and G for a range)

A--B--C  (branch-foo)
 \
  \
   D-(E--F--G) detached
   ^-- (branch-bar)

Switch to branch-foo
$ git cherry-pick E..G

A--B--C--E'--F'--G' (branch-foo)
 \   E--F--G detached (This can be ignored)
  \ /
   D--H--I (branch-bar)

Now you won't need to worry about the detached branch because it is basically
like they are in the trash can waiting for the day it gets garbage collected.
Eventually some time in the far future it will look like:

A--B--C--E'--F'--G'--L--M--N--... (branch-foo)
 \
  \
   D--H--I--J--K--.... (branch-bar)
```

Comment: Yes you could alternatively use `rebase` on the detached branch in the scenario above.

Answer (score 30):

To do this without rewriting history (i.e. if you've already pushed the commits):

```
git checkout master
git revert <commitID(s)>
git checkout -b new-branch
git cherry-pick <commitID(s)>
```

Both branches can then be pushed without force!

Comment: But then you have to deal with the revert scenario, which, depending on your circumstance, can be a lot trickier. If you revert a commit on the branch, Git will still see those commits as have taken place, so in order to undo that, you have to revert the revert.  This burns quite a few people, especially when they revert a merge and try to merge the branch back, only to find that Git believes that it's already merged that branch in (which is entirely true).

Comment: That's why I cherry-pick the commits at the end, onto a new branch. That way git sees them as new commits, which solves your issue.

Comment: This is more dangerous than it first seems, since you're changing the state of the repository's history without really understanding the implications of this state.

Comment: I don't follow your argument - the point of this answer is that you're not changing history, simply adding new commits (which effectively undo the redo the changes). These new commits can be pushed and merged as normal.

Answer (score 15):

How can I go from this

```
A - B - C - D - E 
                |
                master
```

to this?

```
A - B - C - D - E 
    |           |
    master      newbranch
```

With two commands

- **git branch -m master newbranch**

giving

```
A - B - C - D - E 
                |
                newbranch
```

and

- **git branch master B**

giving

```
A - B - C - D - E
    |           |
    master      newbranch
```

Comment: Yep, this works and is quite easy. Sourcetree GUI is a little confused about the changes made in the git shell, but after a fetch it's all right again.

Comment: Yes, they are as in the question. The first couple of diagrams are intended to be equivalent to those in the question, just redrawn the way I would like for the purpose of illustration in the answer. Basically rename the master branch as newbranch and create a new master branch where you want it.

Answer (score 14):

Had just this situation:

```
Branch one: A B C D E F     J   L M  
                       \ (Merge)
Branch two:             G I   K     N
```

I performed:

```
git branch newbranch 
git reset --hard HEAD~8 
git checkout newbranch
```

I expected that commit I would be the HEAD, but commit L is it now...

To be sure to land on the right spot in the history its easier to work with the hash of the commit

```
git branch newbranch 
git reset --hard #########
git checkout newbranch
```

Answer (score 11):

If you just need to move all your **unpushed** commits to a *new branch*,
then you just need to,

1. **create** a *new branch* from the current one :`git branch new-branch-name`
2. **push** your *new branch*: `git push origin new-branch-name`
3. **revert** your *old(current) branch* to the last pushed/stable state: `git reset --hard origin/old-branch-name`

Some people also have other `upstreams` rather than `origin`, 
they should use appropriate `upstream`

Answer (score 11):

TLDR

```bash
git checkout branch_to_remove_commits
git reset --hard ${hash_of_new_tip}
git checkout -b branch_to_store_commits
# Move commits (single hash, list of hashes or range ffaa..ffoo) 
git cherry-pick ${commit_hash}
git push --set-upstream origin branch_to_store_commits
# Switch back to last branch
git checkout -
git push -f
```

For me

```
git log --pretty=oneline -n ${NUMBER}
```

works best to identify the commit hashes in question.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this is just 3  simple step that i used.

1) make new branch where you want to commit you recent update.

**`git branch <branch name>`**

2)  Find  Recent Commit Id for commit on new branch.

**`git log`**

3)  Copy that commit id  note that Most Recent commit list take place on top. so you can find your commit. you also find this via message.

**`git cherry-pick d34bcef232f6c...`**

you can also provide some rang of commit id.

**`git cherry-pick d34bcef...86d2aec`**

Now your job done. If you picked correct id and correct branch then you will success. So before do this be careful. else another problem can occur.

Now you can push your code

**`git push`**

Answer (score 6):

I was surprised that nobody recommended this way:

```
git checkout master
git checkout <commit hash from which you want to split>
git checkout -b new_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit hash you splitted>
```

to explain:

1. step we checking out the commit where we want to split
2. then from this commit creating a new branch
3. doing rebase will synchronize new_branch and master. So now we have two same branches with same commits
4. with reset on master, we cleanup last commits after split
5. List item

Comment: This way only creates a branch with the first commit that changes from Main/Master, but forgets about the rest.

Answer (score 5):

1) Create a new branch, which moves all your changes to new_branch.

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

2) Then go back to old branch.

```
git checkout master
```

3) Do git rebase

```
git rebase -i <short-hash-of-B-commit>
```

4) Then the opened editor contains last 3 commit information.

```
...
pick <C's hash> C
pick <D's hash> D
pick <E's hash> E
...
```

5) Change `pick` to `drop` in all those 3 commits. Then save and close the editor.

```
...
drop <C's hash> C
drop <D's hash> D
drop <E's hash> E
...
```

6) Now last 3 commits are removed from current branch (`master`). Now push the branch forcefully, with `+` sign before branch name.

```
git push origin +master
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Emacs' git porcelain Magit, you can do this simply by hitting `b s` (magit-branch-spinoff). You'll be asked to enter a name for your new branch and once you hit enter, voila.

From the [Magit documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Branch-Commands.html):

> This command creates and checks out a new branch starting at and tracking the current branch. That branch in turn is reset to the last commit it shares with its upstream. If the current branch has no upstream or no unpushed commits, then the new branch is created anyway and the previously current branch is not touched.
>
> This is useful to create a feature branch after work has already began on the old branch (likely but not necessarily "master").

Answer (score 4):

Most of the solutions here count the amount of commits you'd like to go back. I think this is an error prone methodology. Counting would require recounting.

You can simply pass the commit hash of the commit you want to be at HEAD or in other words, the commit you'd like to be the last commit via:

(Notice see commit hash)

To avoid this:

```
1) git checkout master

2) git branch <feature branch> master

3) git reset --hard <commit hash>

4) git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the files affected by the 3 commits back to *Staged* and then re-commit the code to a new branch. Assuming you're on `master` and want to move exactly 3 commits to `new-branch`:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git checkout -b new-branch
git commit -m "message"
```

The code is now committed with a new hash into `new-branch`, avoiding any future rebase-issues highlighted by some other answers. To avoid any merge conflicts, push `master`:

```
git checkout master
git push -ff
```

This solution also provides the flexibility to re-create your commits completely. In the example above, I replace 3 commits with 1 commit. However, you can of course unstage your staged files by replacing the `commit`-step above with:

```
git reset                        # unstage all files
git add path/file_1
git commit -m "first-commit"
git add path/file_2
git commit -m "second-commit"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got to move 7 commits from one old-branch to a new-branch.

```
git checkout old-branch     # in the example, master
git reset --hard h4sh       # h4sh is the hash for the commit 
git checkout -b new-branch  
git push origin new-branch
```

After that, both branches were related to the 7 commits I have done. After `git checkout new-branch`, I was getting fine `git log` and `git status`, but, when accessing the old-branch (`git checkout old-branch`), I'd got the message "git is behind by 7 commits and can be fast-forwarded". What worked for me to erase this message was the followind:

```
git checkout old-branch
git status 
> git is behind by 7 commits and can be fast-forwarded
git push origin old-branch -f
```

After that step, the last 7 commits was referenced only for the new-branch and the previous ones were referenced as old-branch and new-branch in the Bitbucket tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a UI person like me and you are using Visual Studio. Then you can do the following:
In my case, I want to take the latest commit to another branch.

1. Right-click on the one (commit) before.

[image]

2. So all commit changes will appear in the **Git Changes** pane.
3. Now, stash your changes

[image]

4. Go to your targeted branch or create a new one from the bottom right corner.

[image]

5. From "Git Changes" double click on your latest Stash.
6. "Stash details" pane will be opened. Click on "Pop", then resolve conflicts (if exists).

[image]

7. And finally, commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved like this, considering "E" as the hash of the last commit and "B" the hash of the commit that I want the master to point to:

```
git branch new_branch E
git branch --force master B
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git push -u origin newbranch
git checkout oldbranch
git revert --no-commit <hash-to-keep>..HEAD
git commit -m Reverting the previous three commits
git push
```

The "-u origin newbranch" was needed on "git push" because there was no new commit. My changes were on a new branch, where they belonged. Everyone who had unpushed commits just needed to pull, and they'd see no conflicts. I'd tried to use a couple of the other solutions here, but my remote would not allow me to rewrite history.

Answer (score -1):

Taking some ideas from other posts, avoiding anything to do with reset, and being ultra paranoid, my solution is:

1. git branch   # changes are available in new branch
2. git push      # upload, you may need to mess with "--set-upstream", e.g. git push --set-upstream https:///
3. check the new branch is in git via a GUI
4. destroy current directory
5. re-clone from git repository

I'm not proud, but I kept my data ;)