# How to move certain commits to be based on another branch in git?

Tags: git, commit, patch

The situation:

- master is at X
- quickfix1 is at X + 2 commits

Such that:

```
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \
      q1a--q1b (quickfix1 HEAD)
```

Then I started working on quickfix2, but by accident took quickfix1 as the source branch to copy, not the master. Now quickfix2 is at X + 2 commits + 2 relevant commits.

```
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \
      q1a--q1b (quickfix1 HEAD)
              \
               q2a--q2b (quickfix2 HEAD)
```

Now I want to have a branch with quickfix2, but without the 2 commits that belong to quickfix1.

```
      q2a'--q2b' (quickfix2 HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      q1a--q1b (quickfix1 HEAD)
```

I tried to create a patch from a certain revision in quickfix2, but the patch doesn't preserve the commit history. Is there a way to save my commit history, but have a branch without changes in quickfix1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: @Kevin That question only asks about moving commits from one branch to another, this one has the additional requirement of *not* including the commits on `quickfix1`. (Note also the difference in answers.)

Answer (score 418, accepted):

This is a classic case of **[`rebase --onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491)**:

```sh
 # let's go to current master (X, where quickfix2 should begin)
 git checkout master

 # replay every commit *after* quickfix1 up to quickfix2 HEAD.
 git rebase --onto master quickfix1 quickfix2
```

So you should go from

```
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      q1a--q1b (quickfix1 HEAD)
              \
               q2a--q2b (quickfix2 HEAD)
```

to:

```
      q2a'--q2b' (new quickfix2 HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      q1a--q1b (quickfix1 HEAD)
```

This is best done on a clean working tree.
[See `git config --global rebase.autostash true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), especially [after Git 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38436051/6309).

Comment: Beware that these steps will modify quickfix2's history, so if you already shared the branch, use cherry-picking instead (see following answers).

Comment: Just for the records: with SmartGit's log just drag `q2a` onto `X` and select *Rebase 2 commits* from the options of the occurring dialog.

Comment: @ThomasS. Interesting. That is a nice GUI implementation of a `git rebase --onto`.

Comment: I have to admit, I do silly things like committing on to the wrong branch more often that I really should, the SmartGit log view GUI has saved me so many times with the same situation.

Comment: @WORMSS another interesting GUI: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/diffplug/git-for-diffplug

Comment: Careful! If not careful this will overwrite your working directory. I lost work with this command.

Comment: @Cosine Agreed. I have edited my answer to add the reference to `rebase.autostash` configuration: that will avoid any loss of work in progress in the working tree when doing a rebase.

Answer (score 179):

You can use `git cherry-pick` to just pick the commit that you want to copy over.

Probably the best way is to create the branch out of master, then in that branch use `git cherry-pick` on the 2 commits from quickfix2 that you want.

Comment: This is also the best option if you want to move just one commit. Thanks.

Answer (score 170):

The simplest thing you can do is cherry picking a range. It does the same as the `rebase --onto` but is easier for the eyes :)

```
git cherry-pick quickfix1..quickfix2
```

Comment: also, it doesn't lose the original commits, IIUC, so seems preferable for "play-it-safes" like me ;) or does `rebase --onto` also preserve the original changes?

Comment: both `rebase` and `cherry-pick` give you new SHA keys. That's because each commit is a **unique** snapshot of the repository.

Comment: What @akavel meant is that cherry-pick will keep the original commits in their branch which is true

Comment: For whatever it is worth, I tried to `cherry-pick` a range like in this answer and it confused my repo.  I had to do individual `cherry-pick`s for each commit.  (And maybe it goes without saying, but in case anyone is struggling, you have to `cherry-pick` in the chronological order that your commits were applied.)

Comment: `git checkout` is crucial here. what is your HEAD :) ?

Answer (score 35):

I believe it's:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b good_quickfix2
git cherry-pick quickfix2^
git cherry-pick quickfix2
```

Comment: `cherry-pick` works with commit hashes so, if you just want to grab a commit from somewhere and put it somewhere else this is the way to go. Just make sure you do the `checkout <branch>` of the correct branch first.

Answer (score -2):

```
// on your branch that holds the commit you want to pass
$ git log
// copy the commit hash found
$ git checkout [branch that will copy the commit]
$ git reset --hard [hash of the commit you want to copy from the other branch]
// remove the [brackets]
```

Other more useful commands here with explanation: [Git Guide](https://github.com/vindecodex/gitguide#passing-commits-to-another-branch)