# Git: move specific commits to another branch

Tags: git, git-commit

A have repository with two branches.

Master branch commits:

c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, ..., c15, ...

Staging Branch commits:

c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7

I want to move all commits from Master branch after **c7** to staging branch

and then revert Master branch

with

```
git reset --hard c7-hash
```

How to move/copy specific commits from one branch to another ?

Comment: In this case you don't have to move commits because staging branch can be fast-forwarded to master.
`git checkout staging`, 
`git merge master`,
`git checkout master`,
`git reset --hard c7-hash`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move certain commits to another branch in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369426/how-to-move-certain-commits-to-another-branch-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move recent commit(s) to a new branch with git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/how-can-i-move-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the case you've described, where all commits on the staging branch are also on the master branch, it's very easy:

```
git checkout staging
git merge master
git checkout master
git reset --hard c7-hash
```

The merge will be a fast-forward.

In the general case, you can use `git cherry-pick c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15` to cherry pick individual commits to the current branch. A shorter way to cherry pick all commits that are on master but not the current branch is `git cherry-pick ..master`, and there are other examples shown by `git help cherry-pick`

Comment: After doing this let's say you commit `x` to the master branch.   And then you merge master into staging.  Would that merge into staging correctly merge `x` into staging while _not_ reverting c8...c15 in staging due to the fact those commits were already reset in master?   Want to ensure c8...c15 stay in staging after that merge.

Comment: @MarcusLeon, merging won't revert those commits. Those commits were not reverted in master, they were removed completely. A reset is not a revert. It's easy to create test commits and test scenarios like that, try it.