# Changing source branch in git

Tags: git, git-remote

I was wondering if it possible to change the source branch from which I created branch, the thing is, months ago I had a branch created from dev branch, meanwhile, month later, we create our branches from release branch, how to solve this issue?

Comment: The function is called "rebase". **Note:** Make a copy of your local clone and experiment in the copy. If you get merge conflicts or whatnot in the rebase process, **don't *muddle* through**, get help.

Comment: rebase is for PR only right?
If a branch is created from dev branch there is no way to change that unless we create a branch again from release branch and cherry pick or commit all the changes/commits? @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen

Comment: @LunaLovegood No, rebase is not for PRs only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move certain commits to be based on another branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369426/how-to-move-certain-commits-to-be-based-on-another-branch-in-git)