# I branched off the wrong branch, how do I move my changes to correct branch?

Tags: git

We have a `develop` branch and a `release` branch.

I was asked to make a change, but was later told that the change had to be a **hotfix** and so I should have branched off the `release` branch.

The current situation is this (I drew the diagram myself):

[image: git branching]

I **really** don't want to loose all my work that is currently sitting on my `feature-branch`. How do I move all my changes in `feature-branch` so that they **sit in a new branch** but *one that is branched off* `release` branch?

**What have I tried?**

I tried using `rebase --onto` but I got the following error:

> $ git rebase --onto release-branch feature/1 feature/1a
>
> fatal: fatal: no such branch/commit 'feature/1a'

Comment: Create a branch from Release and then merge the Feature branch into that branch (and then delete the Feature branch that's from Develop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move certain commits to be based on another branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369426/how-to-move-certain-commits-to-be-based-on-another-branch-in-git)

Comment: Plenty of existing questions for this exact scenario exist; what have you tried?

Comment: @auburg if OP does that, a later feature > release pull request will merge develop into release, which I guess is unwanted. No, you'd have to rebase the feature branch on release.

Comment: @RomainValeri is right, I don't want anything else going into the release branch, just my changes.

Comment: @J86 Ahh, point taken - then a rebase is what you need

Comment: @J86 No need for `--onto`. Check Kerim's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To duplicate the commits from `feature`, and only them (no commit from `develop` before or after `feature` forked from it), you can use the following commands:

```
git checkout -B feature release      # Checkout `release` and bring `feature` along
git cherry-pick develop..feature@{1} # Retrieve commits from `feature` which are not on `develop`
```

Comment: I am currently on the release branch @Quentin. I'm not sure what `git checkout -B feature release` will do. I know you've said that it will checkout `release` but I'm already on that branch? I already have that branch checked out?

Comment: @J86 no harm done. It's just a fast way to attach to `feature` and reset it to the current tip of `release`.

Comment: Do I have to cherry-pick commit by commit? I believe this is cherry-picking one single commit? `git cherry-pick develop..feature@{1}`

Comment: Thank you, I also watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ndmel-4wsk) before doing anything. Things are now how I wanted them.

Comment: @J86 I guess you've found out already, but `develop..feature@{1}` is the set of commits that are reachable from the previous position of `feature`, but not from `develop`.

Comment: The comment on this is misleading: 'git checkout -B feature release      # Checkout release and bring feature along'.  More accurate would be: "create a new feature branch pointing to the tip of the release branch and check that out."

Comment: @DavidSugar since `feature` supposedly exists already, it is moved (hence `-B` rather than `-b`).

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is to rebase your Feature branch onto Release. 
The git rebase command is quite flexible. You can tell it where to move your branch, and how much of your branch to move.

This command will move the Feature branch to branch off Release, starting from the commit after the Develop branch:

```
git rebase --onto Release Develop Feature
```

or alternatively:

```
git checkout Feature
git rebase --onto Release Develop
```

No need to create a new branch or delete your original one.

Comment: Note that this does rewrite history. I doubt that is important in this case. If it is, then you will want to create a new branch that you will rebase and keep your original Feature branch as is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands (pseudo-code: apply your naming correctly)

```
git checkout release
git rebase feature
```

After these commands, you will have work from `feature` branch in `release` branch.

However if `develop` has accepted commits after `feature` branch was checked out, those commits will not be present nor in `feature` nor in `release`.

You will need to rebase your `release` branch agains master in order to have them in `release` branch. By running:

```
git checkout release
git rebase develop
```

P.S. Here is the link that describes the `rebase` command https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: That will also bring in all of the commits from `develop`, though.

Comment: True, so as an alternative you could possibly do cherry-pick. But that's an even hairier proposition.