# Point branch to new commit

Tags: git

*(This question is the opposite of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/git-move-recent-commit-to-a-new-branch))*

How can I go from this

```
dev            C - D
             /
master A - B
```

to this?

```
dev                D
                 /
master A - B - C
```

I know I'm going to kick myself when I see the answer, but for the moment I'm a bit stuck...

Answer (score 123, accepted):

#### Solution

```
git checkout master
git merge C
```

*With `C` being the SHA1 of commit `C`.*

#### Result

```
                 D (dev)
                /
master A - B - C (move master HEAD)
```

It should be a fast-forward merge.

Answer (score 22):

Necromancy, I know.

```
git branch -f master C
```

Will not touch current working tree at all - you can have your work in progress.

Comment: Does it need to be done when being on a specific branch or not?

Comment: You can be on any branch, except, maybe, master.