# Unable to Push Master After Resetting, Branching, and Merging

Tags: git

I made a few unstable commit changes that were also pushed.  My imaginary commit tree is as follows:

> A -> B -> C -> D

Commit "A" was the latest stable commit.  Upon finding that the later changes were unstable, I went back to the last stable revision using

> git checkout A

I then created a new branch "stable" with

> git checkout -b stable

And continued working in that branch.  Now I want to merge to master, but I don't want to delete the changes I previously had, so I wanted to add them to a new branch instead of using revert.  Following the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492536/point-branch-to-new-commit), I did the following from the master branch:

> git branch unstable
>
> git reset --hard HEAD~3

So now HEAD points to commit A, and the new branch "unstable" starts at commit B.  But I want to merge my stable changes (in branch "stable") so I use

> git merge stable

And it completes successfully with no conflicts, and HEAD now points to the latest revision with the the stable changes merged in.  I can now push all branches to my repository except master, which reports a non-fast-forward error.  If I pull, it seems to pull all the unstable changes I had from earlier.

There appears to be a large number of posts similar to this, but it seems that mostly people want to just use revert to undo the commits they had, whereas I want to keep my unstable commits, but in a separate branch as I have it now.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question here is whether anyone else is using your master branch, and might already fetched that version.  If not, then it's safe for you to do a "forced" push, which will overwrite the old version of `master`.  You can do that with:

```
 git push -f origin master
```

However, if anyone might have used the `master` branch, you don't want to rewrite public history.  In that case, you can do:

```
 git fetch origin
 git merge -s ours origin/master
 git push origin master
```

The "ours" merge strategy says to create a merge commit, but ignore all the content that you're merging in (i.e. your old master branch).  Then your history will contain the history of `master` in `origin`, so you'll be able to push it without having to use the `-f` (`--force`) option.

Your `unstable` branch will still exist locally in both cases, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Mark; I had forgotten to reply.  I was ironically contacted back around the time you posted by someone I had called for help previously and we were able to get the situation resolved by fast-forwarding the "unstable" branch (which, along with origin/HEAD, pointed to commit D), and completing a merge of "stable" into "master" with a method similar to what you described here.  I didn't have anyone else working on it at the time, thankfully, but I didn't have to --force it either.