# Creating git branch after many commits

Tags: git, version-control, github, branch

I have a repo on GitHub with a single branch `master` that I've been working on in my local repo.  At some point I stopped pushing commits back up to master on GitHub because I was worried that they'd break things. Now I have lots of commits in my local repo that I want to push back up to GitHub.

However, rather than pushing back up to master I would prefer to create a new branch on GitHub (`development`) and push all my local commits back up to that branch (which I will merge back into master only after they've been better tested).

What is the simple way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move recent commit(s) to a new branch with git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/how-can-i-move-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

on master:

`git checkout -b newbranch` or as suggested below, simply do a `git branch newbranch` to create the new branch without switching to it.

This will create a branch that is at your current commit at master.  Once done:

`git checkout master`

followed by:

`git reset --hard <commit_hash>`

Where `<commit_hash>` should be replaced by the commit ID you want master rolled back to.

Now you can switch to your new branch and push it out to the remote.

```
git checkout newbranch
git push origin newbranch
```

Comment: And maybe a `git branch --set-upstream newbranch origin/newbranch` to set up tracking :)

Comment: If you just do 'git branch newbranch', instead of 'git checkout -b newbranch; git checkout master' then the branch will get created pointing to the proper commit, without actually changing branches.

Comment: Also, if you want to restore the master branch to the last github push, you should set the <commit_hash> value to HEAD in git reset --hard <commit_hash>: git reset --hard HEAD will do it.

Comment: @Grant -- Thanks very much, that did the trick!  Makes sense to me now, but it would have taken me a while to get there myself.  One question:  If I simply wanted my local Master to be same as github Master could I have used `git checkout origin/master` (or Emmanuel suggestion in comment above) rather than the hard reset to the commit-hash?  If so, would I have had to delete my local Master first (and would I have done that by switching to my new development branch and issuing `git branch -d master`)?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Herbert: First, you probably want to use `origin/master` (or an equivalent name for the same object) as `<commit_hash>` in Grant’s command. Second, if you want to move your local `master` to wherever `origin/master` points, then it is best to do it directly (since deleting and recreating it would also restart its reflog). If `master` is checked out, then `git reset --hard origin/master`. If it is not checked out, then `git branch -f master origin/master`. Your `git checkout origin/master` would check out the commit as a detached HEAD, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Chris -- Thanks, that was helpful, I'll grok this stuff yet.