# How do I synchronise remote repository after moving local changes on master to a branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I followed the instructions given in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/how-can-i-move-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git) to move recently committed changed to a branch instead.

In short, I did the following on my local repo,

```
git branch newbranch
git reset --hard HEAD~3 # Go back three commits
git checkout newbranch
```

My remote repo (which only I access) however still has the commits in master.

I can't at present push the changes to remote because the local repo is missing some commits and it asks me to merge in changes through a pull.

How can I get the remote repo to reflect the new branch?

Comment: Master branch of the remote? Please add some more detail/elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use the `-f` flag to force push to the remote repo.

```
git push -f
```

> -f, --force
>
> Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an
>   ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables
>   the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits;
>   use it with care.

More at: [git-push(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Answer (score 1):

If the remote repository you push to has been initialized properly with

```
git init --bare --shared
```

then

```
git push -f
```

will still fail because the git config file will contain

```
[receive]
    denyNonFastforwards = true
```

The commit you are trying to push is a non fast forward commit so you will need to change the behavior (at least temporarily) to allow non fast forward commits. I usually just uncomment the line above but you can do it with the official git config interface.