# Move specific git commit from master to branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a specific commit that was pushed into origin/master but was not ready for prime time. It should have gone into a separate existing feature branch that will eventually be merged into master. How can I pluck the commit out of master and move it into the feature branch?

Here's what I have in the remote branches:

```
          a     B     c     d
master -  o --- o --- o --- o -->
                   \
newbranch -         - o --- o -->
                      p     q
```

The errant commit `B` needs to be moved to `newbranch`:

```
          a     c     d
master -  o --- o --- o -->
             \
newbranch -   - o --- o --- o -->
                B     p     q
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move recent commit(s) to a new branch with git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/how-can-i-move-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: Have you already pushed to origin?  If so, you won't be able to achieve this with force-pushing, which will make the rest of your team sad.  In which case, you should just `git revert B` on `master`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, the commit was pushed to origin. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already pushed the commit, then any attempt to rewrite the existing graph will require a force-push, which will make other members of your team sad.

Therefore, the best solution is to simply commit a revert to `master`:

```
git checkout master
git revert B   # Or whatever the commit hash for B is
```