# Creating new branches in GIT and carrying over code changes

Tags: git, github

When using GIT i normally create feature branches off an updated master branch then once i have completed work i merge the feature branch back in to the remote master branch.

To do this i normally switch to the local master branch, do a `git pull` and use `git checkout -b 'myFeatureBranchName'` which will create & switch me to a new local branch. I do my changes commit and push then merge back into to master.

However, in this instance i have switched to master done a `git pull` but forgot to create and switch to a new branch. Is there a command that will allow me to create & switch to a new feature branch and also carry over all my changes to the new branch?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Your question actually contains the answer to your question.  You can use this command:

```
git checkout -b 'myFeatureBranchName'
```

This will create a new feature branch from `master` containing all of your work.  You can push this branch to the remote, issue a pull request, and merge in as normal.

However, there is one lingering issue about what to do with your local `master` branch, since it will now contain new commits which really belonged only in the feature branch.  Here are two options you can consider:

One is to rollback `master` to before you started making commits for the feature.  You can nuke the commits in `master` which don't really belong there.  If there were 3 commits in `master`, you would do this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

The second option is to delete your local `master` branch and then simply do a `git pull` to get a fresh one from the remote:

```
git branch -d master
git checkout --track -b origin/master
```

In either case, you now have your feature branch pushed out to GitHub and your local `master` is in the correct state.

Comment: Hi @VonC Yes I would like to join the Git team.  I don't use Twitter that often but here is my email: TimBeagle@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this question: [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Pro tip: Never work on the master branch. Branch it off to a 'develop' branch, and create your feature branches from there.