# Git: Effect of reset --hard on future merging

Tags: git, merge, git-reset

We accidentally committed sha XXX to branch A instead of B.

```
A: VVV-WWW-XXX
B: VVV-WWW
```

So we'll follow the [guidance on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628584/47281) to move the commit from A to B:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
git checkout A
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push --force
```

That will get us to:

```
A: VVV-WWW
B: VVV-WWW-XXX
```

If we then do commit YYY on branch A giving us:

```
A: VVV-WWW-YYY
B: VVV-WWW-XXX
```

And merge that into B will that cleanly merge YYY into B while *not* reverting XXX on B due to the fact that XXX was `reset --hard` previously on A?   What we'd want following the merge is:

```
A: VVV-WWW-YYY
B: VVV-WWW-XXX-YYY
```

I'm struggling with the affect of `reset --hard` on the merging behavior.  I think that reset wipes any history of the commit so the merge would just work without attempting to remove XXX from B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the merge will be

```
                (A)
VVV --- WWW --- YYY
          \         \   (B)
            --- XXX --- ZZZ
```

Where ZZZ is merge commit whose parents are XXX and YYY. The single letters in parentheses represent refs or branch names, which are merely signposts along the way in a history graph.

As rendered with [`git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) (a handy alias for `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all`)

```
*   78d2930 (HEAD -> B) ZZZ
|\
| * 549c09e (A) YYY
* | f585976 XXX
|/
* 537d898 WWW
* 875611c VVV
```

I used commit messages above to tie to the history in your question. Your SHA-1 object names will differ from those above.

Don’t overthink it. Keep in mind that git stores snapshots of tree states, and historical pedigree comes from the commit objects. Using the sharp tool `git reset --hard` removes history as though it never occurred with no trails left behind.

Like any sharp tool, `git reset --hard` can cut you if you aren’t careful. Think about it like `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 2):

`reset` just moves the HEAD/branch pointer to another commit. It will not have any effect on the repository or any future operations at all.

You are correct in that future merges will work exactly the same regardless of if you  made a commit you the reseted or not.