# How to safely undo commits that already in remote master branch & move them into another branch?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch

I'm working on a feature right now which I suppose to do it in a `featureX` branch BUT I forgot to create that branch and checkout into it. That cause a problem right now because that 2 commits already in my team remote master branch (we're using BitBucket) like so:

[image]

How do I move `d40ef79` and `5e13fd7` into `featureX` branch so that I can continue working on that `featureX` branch and remove that 2 commits from master branch without losing recent commits created by my teammates (`29ac4fb..1606c1a`)?

I try first option inside [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628584/1577357) and it doesn't work for me. I also try `git cherry-pick` inside `featureX` branch (branch off from master) - also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to do revert.

### ***`git revert <SHA-1>`***

Undo the git commit. Revert the changes made by the given commit.

### ***`reset and force push`***

```
# reset the branch to the desired commit
git reset <SHA-1>
```

---

There are other ways as well but they are less recommended (`git push -f`, `git rebase`, `git filter-branch`)

---

#### How to add the desired commit into different branch.

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>...<SHA-1>`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

The syntax of the `...` is a commit range. grab all commits from start (exclude) to the last one.

[image]

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)