# Git: Create new Branch after Commit before Pushing

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to know if and how I can create a new branch when I had already committed but not pushed.

Scenario:

1. Switch to Master
2. Change something
3. Commit changes
4. Create new Branch instead of Push

Basically I was told that this is not possible and that one has to push before creating a new branch. Since I did two days of work (like 10+ commits) and came to the conclusion that I would rather create a new branch instead of pushing these changes to master (I want to do additional testing prior since the changes became more bigger than anticipated).

Would I need to save all mal files, recheckout the master version I started with, create a new branch from it and restore my changes and recommit or can I just create a new branch which I originally thought (so I did not care at first)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically I was told that this is not possible and that one has to push before creating a new branch.

That is absolutely not the case.  You can create a new branch whenever you want.  For example, after you had committed your changes, you could run:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

And that would create a new branch named `newbranch` based on the current commit.  If you want to revert the `master` branch as part of this operation (that is, you want your changes only on the new branch, not on the master branch) you could do this:

```
# create a new branch, but don't switch to it
git branch newbranch

# Reset current (master) branch by discarding the most recent
# commit.
git reset --hard HEAD^

# Switch to new branch
git checkout newbranch
```

And now you can push your new branch to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Create a branch with your latest commits:

```
git branch newbranch
```

Reset your `maste`r branch to the server state:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Check out the `newbranch`:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

[See more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628584/3506292)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `git branch new_branchname`. The default starting position is `HEAD`. It can be changed if you wish by adding it as a second parameter to `git branch`.

What you do have now is that the new commit is still present on `master`, which seems to me is not the final intention. You'll need to `revert` that or even `reset` (because it hasn't been pushed this is fine).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git checkout dde0f681c20791aee8dcc0f31b41850f83c5b778 (id commit )


$ git checkout -b before_bo 

$ git push --set-upstream origin before_bo

$ git checkout master
```