# How to move (unpushed) commits from one branch to the other

Tags: git

I was on `branch-x` and made few changes and committed them (but did not push). Although the commits were correct, they should not have been made in `branch-x` but instead in `branch-y`. How can I take the commits from `branch-x` and apply them to `branch-y`. I want to avoid pushing the committed changes from `branch-x`.

Below is what I did in commands.

```
(branch-x)$: git status
(branch-x)$: git add .
(branch-x)$: git commit -m "some commit"
<oops, I should have made these changes in branch-y>
(branch-x)$: git checkout -b branch-y
(branch-y)$: <how can I take the commit from branch-x and apply it here?>
```

Comment: Your example shows you creating a *new* `branch-y`, rather than working on an *existing* `branch-y`; is that what you intend?

Comment: yes, that is intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already created the branch you want via `git checkout -b branch-y`, and this new branch has the commit you want, then the only remaining problem is an extra rogue commit on the tip of `branch-x`.  Since you did not publish `branch-x` yet, you should be safe in rewriting that history.  Do this:

```
git checkout branch-x    # switch back to branch-x
git reset --hard HEAD~1  # nuke the rogue commit on the tip of this branch
```

Comment: I would recommend cherry picking over reset --hard. It is safer.

Comment: @Edvin I think you misunderstood the original problem.  Branch `branch-y` already has the commits he wants.  He only needs to remove the unwanted commit from `branch-x`.  I originally answered using `git cherry-pick` but then revised it.

Comment: Oh, okey. This comment "How can I take the commits from branch-x and apply them to branch-y." is a bit miss leading then.

Comment: @Edvin Yup.  My first answer used `cherry-pick`, and I edited it after the comment by @torek was addressed.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use `git cherry-pick`.  Suppose we have the commit graph like this.

```
A-B-C-D-E->branch-x
M-N->branch-y
```

Now you want CDE to be on branch-y.

```
git checkout branch-y
git cherry-pick C D E
```

or

```
git cherry-pick C^..E
```

and we get

```
M-N-C'-D'-E'->branch-y
```

Another possible solution is to use `git rebase`.

```
git rebase --onto branch_y C^ E
git branch -d branch_y
git checkout -b branch_y
```