# Moving Just one commit from Branch A to Branch B

Tags: git

I am sure this question is duplicate, but I am not able to find the right answer because of too many answers being returned and each one is not working for me.

I have branch A with commits 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 (commit 6 is the most recent).

I have branch B with commits 1 -> 2 (2 is the most recent)

I just want to move commit 6 from branch A to branch B. So 3, 4, 5, should remain in branch A.... I just take commit 6 and move it to branch B.

The end result I want is

A =  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6
B =  1 -> 2 -> 6

is this possible? and sorry if this is FAQ, duplicate or just illogical.

I googled but all answers I found pointed me to conclusion that every commit before 6 will also move... so there is no way for me to take 6 without taking 3, 4, 5

I googling I found this tutorial

https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/

but here also, once the cherry pick is done both the commits 76cada - 62ecb3 move to master. I want only 62ecb3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: the problem with the solutoin you point is that with the most recent commit, all commits before them also move. I don't want the commits before the most recent commit. only the most recent commit. I just want the E. I don't want C and D.

Comment: You mentioned: "The end result I want is A = 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 B = 1 -> 2 -> 6". So, do you want to keep commit `6` in both `A` & `B` branches?

Comment: It's not possible, as asked. The reason is that Git's commit-connecting backwards arrows (all Git's pointers work backwards, from newest back to oldest) are *part of* the commit. Your commit 6 already exists. It points to your commit 5. It is literally impossible to change this: commit 6 will forever point to commit 5. The best you can do is, as in Sukima's answer, *copy* commit 6 to a new, slightly different copy, that points somewhere else, such as to commit 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git checkout branch-B
$ git cherry-pick commit-6
$ git checkout branch-A
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

It looks like this `git checkout branch-B` :

```
A--B            (branch-B) (HEAD)
    \
     C--D--E--F (branch-A)
```

`git cherry-pick F`:

```
A--B--F'         (branch-B) (HEAD)
    \
     C--D--E--F  (branch-A)
```

`git checkout branch-A`:

```
A--B--F'         (branch-B)
    \
     C--D--E--F  (branch-A) (HEAD)
```

`git reset --hard HEAD^`:

```
A--B--F'         (branch-B)
    \
     C--D--E     (branch-A) (HEAD)
            \
             F   (detached and will be garbage collected)
```