# Why does git reset --hard cause derived branches to also reset when being rebased?

Tags: git

Sometimes I want to split my latest work on a branch into a new branch.

```
# Create a new branch tracking the old branch
git branch -t new-branch

# Reset the old branch to a prior commit
git reset --hard HEAD~3

git checkout new-branch
```

I expect `git rebase` to now do nothing, because the docs say:

```
All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in <upstream>
are saved to a temporary area. This is the same set of commits that would be shown
by git log <upstream>..HEAD; or by git log 'fork_point'..HEAD, if --fork-point is
active (see the description on --fork-point below)....
```

So `new-branch` is reset to `old-branch`, and any saved changes are applied. Shouldn't those saved changes include the commits `new-branch` pointed to that were no longer reachable from `old-branch`?

Instead, `new-branch` is reset to `old-branch` and the commits disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs more closely, I found:

```
   If <upstream> is not specified, the upstream configured in branch.<name>.remote
   and branch.<name>.merge options will be used (see git-config(1) for details) and
   the --fork-point option is assumed.
```

So instead of using the commits from `<upstream>..HEAD`, the rebase will use `fork_point..HEAD`. And here's what `fork_point` is:

```
git merge-base --fork-point <upstream> <branch>
```

`merge-base` is complicated, but in this case it checks the reflog and realizes the "new" commits previously existed in the branch we branched from, and returns the same commit as `new-branch`, which is also `HEAD`, so `git log fork_point..HEAD` returns nothing. Then the rebase doesn't end up saving and applying the new commits.

[This is explained in more detail, along with a better way to achieve the new branch, in John Mellor's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git/36463546#36463546)

Comment: Equivalently (but you have to *remember* this), you can use `--no-fork-point` when rebasing later, or be explicit about the local branch upon which you're rebasing even if it's already set as the upstream. It's basically a very bad consequence of the sneaky automatic `--fork-point` code, which was a cool (or "kewl"?) idea way back when but turns out to be more trouble than it's worth, in my opinion. :-)

Comment: (Also, I edited the accepted / community-wiki answer to the original question to add the warning.)