# How to undo commit, put into new branch then do a PR?

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch that is protected with push only by PR.

Say I thoughtlessly on `master`:

```
git add .
git commit -m "bunch of changes"
```

But I push to the branch and am rejected because the branch is protected.
How do I backtrack, preserve my changes, and do a PR?

Comment: Just pull from `origin/master` then rebase onto the latest commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Undo the last commit of `master` branch.

   ```
   $ git reset --soft HEAD~1      # undo the last commit and keep the changes in working tree
   ```
2. Checkout to new branch (say, `feature`), then Add, Commit and Push to remote `feature` branch.

   ```
   $ git checkout -b feature      # create and checkout to new 'feature' branch
   $ git add -A                   # add the changes 
   $ git commit -m 'message'      # commit 
   $ git push origin HEAD         # push to remote 'feature' branch
   ```

Now, Create a PR from `feature` branch.

---

**Alternate:**

1. Checkout to new branch (say, `feature`) and push the `feature` branch to remote.

   ```
   $ git checkout -b feature
   $ git push origin HEAD
   ```
2. Switch to `master` branch and undo the last commit.

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git reset --hard HEAD~1

   Or, (reset the local 'master' with 'origin/master')
   $ git checkout master 
   $ git fetch origin
   $ git reset --hard origin/master
   ```

Now, Create a PR from `feature` branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset HEAD~
git checkout -b "name-of-new-branch"
git -am "my fancy new commit"
git push origin "name-of-new-branch"
```

reset HEAD~ will undo your last commit. Checkout -b makes creates a new branch and checks it out, then you just add and commit your changes there and push