# How to move commits from merged branch?

Tags: git

merged `feature/fix` to `develop`. My collegue after this merge make three commits to `feature/fix`.

How to apply these three commits on develop ?
I know cherry-pick, however I am searching for other solution. Thanks

Comment: Just merge `feature/fix` into `develop` again.

Comment: Or rebase, if for some reason you don't want a merge commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: Personally I would avoid merge at all costs, and go with `rebase`. `git pull --rebase <remote> <branch>`. in this case you can checkout develop, then integrate `feature/fix` using rebase.

Answer (score 4):

Switch to branch 'develop'

> git checkout develop

merge commits of feature fix to develop:

> git merge feature/fix