# in which branch does a git commit end up when being pushed, how to change this if it is not the intended branch

Tags: git

Since nowhere anybody is able to explain the objects involved in git I'm unable to resolve my questions by myself (in contrary to other source code control systems).

I've started working in some cloned repository created by `git clone repository` (this is why I below mention "unnamed branch"):

1) I performed changes

2) I did `git add` and `git commit`

3) I decided that I would like to back this up without disturbing my colleagues. So I did `git branch SomeUniqueName` `git checkout SomeUniqueName`. Now I wonder what will happen if I do a `git push`. If the changes do not end up in the specified branch (SomeUniqueName) but in the unnamed branch, how can I change this? I was already trying to work with another cloned repository and copying my changes. But in this case I don't know how to make the two repositories match the same starting point (in time) -- other developers might have changed the repository meanwhile rendering my changes not working.

Somebody claims, that this question is a duplicate of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563). I cannot relate to this other question, as I already don't know how to extract the list of changes from git. I suspect that this relates to list of commits and that it can be done with "git log" (btw -- when looking at the man page of git-log I'm confused by most of the explained arguments). But when doing a "git log" I get commits performed by other people which did not have access to my working directory. So somehow I remember (When I need my memory, what is the need for a SCCS running on a copputer?) that all the changes performed by me on the top are changes performed only locally in my working directory. So I guess I'll try `git reset --hard HEAD~8; git checkout SomeUniqueName` AFTER I performed a backup of my working directory. And voila -- all my changes are gone. So I've to unpack the just made backup and copy over my changes by hand.

Comment: Which branch did you commit in? The backup only added another pointer, unless you reset the previous branch to an earlier commit.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I specified the sequence of commands already. So the commits were performed in the unnamed branch. Will they end up in this unnamed branch? If so, how can I move these changes to the branch I want them in?

Comment: You need to start with a good tutorial or book on how Git represents commits in a Directed Acyclic Graph, how it uses branch names to store commit hash IDs, and how `git fetch` and `git push` deal with the branch names vs the commit hash IDs. Git's notions are very different from other VCSes. Are you familiar with graph theory? If so, start with http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/

Comment: @torek I don't have a problem understanding graph theory. I just don't know which objects are modified by which git commands. Or even better: I don't know which objects are stored in a local git repository.

Comment: Can you be specific in what you mean by objects?

Comment: OK: so, if you've gone through the link above, you now know which objects are used to store each part. The ID of each object is its hash (SHA-1, at least for now). Normally, every repository stores *every* object required to keep the graph complete, and each external name points to some existing commit object. (Well, let me switch to answer rather than comment...)

Comment: @torek -- so what -- changes are stored as a linked list of changes. I already guessed that changes somehow need to be stored in both the local repository and the remote one. This also does not tell me, how to deduce in which branch my changes will be pushed to.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't tried it yet? Whatever branch you make the commit on, is the branch that will get the changes when you push to the remote. The most straightforward way, if you want those changes on another branch, is to revert the commit, create a new branch, make the changes on that branch, and commit them there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: @evolutionxbox "The backup only added another pointer" -- you lost me.

Comment: A branch is just a named reference to an object.

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming you're good with graph theory and have read through [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/):

- All graph nodes are identified by hash ID.  (The hashes are currently SHA-1s over the object contents prefixed by type-plus-size-plus-a-NUL-byte, not that this matters too much except for correctness.)
- Except for so-called *shallow* clones, which we'll ignore here, every Git repository has *every* reachable commit and *every* reachable object underneath that commit.
- Commits become reachable by having a branch name, or tag name, or any other externally-sourced name, from a second database of *reference names*.  Branch names must point to commit objects.  (Other names, especially tag names, can point to other object types, but again that's not important for our purposes here.)  Branch names are the most interesting case here since that's how we'll build commits and transfer them from one repository to another—but there's a second kind of name, the *remote-tracking name*, that is also key.
- Hence we can draw the commit graph like this for a simple linear case:

  ```
  A  <-B  <-C   <--master
  ```

  The external name `master` contains the hash ID of commit `C`.  This commit object itself contains the hash ID of commit `B`; `B` contains the hash ID of `A`.  `A` has no outgoing arcs (no *parents* as Git puts it) so it is a root commit and the action all stops here.
- *All* objects are read-only at all times.  *Unreachable* objects can be garbage-collected.

Note that no internal object has the ID of `C`, so the fact that `C` is reachable, and hence the chain is retained, only occurs because of the *external* name `refs/heads/master` (branch `master`).

If we add a new branch name, such as `dev`, we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev
```

(the internal arrows in the graph are all still backwards because of the read-only nature of the commit objects, but this gets too painful to draw in text, so I don't bother).  Now Git needs a way to know *which name* to adjust when making new commits, so it attaches the label `HEAD` to some branch name.  `HEAD` can *only* be attached to a branch name!  Let's draw that in:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev (HEAD)
```

To make a *new* commit, Git packages up all the blob hashes stored in the *index* (which we've skipped over here) into a new *tree* object and then creates a new *commit* object pointing to the tree, as in discussed in the "Git for CSists" link above.  The *new* commit will point back to whichever commit `HEAD` indirectly points to:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

and then Git will just overwrite whichever *name* `HEAD` is attached to, so that the names are:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

#### Push and fetch transfer objects, then set names

We now have almost everything we need to understand both `git push` and `git fetch`.  Let's look at `push` first since you're more concerned with it.

Your Git will call up some other Git and hand over a hash ID, such as that for your new commit `D`.  The other Git has no *name* for this ID yet, it just checks to see if it has the hash ID.  If not, it needs the commit (and probably the tree and blob objects as well), so it says "send me those objects".  Your Git packs them up and sends them over.  They put the commit `D` and its sub-objects into their graph, but as yet *they* have *no name* for this object.

Now your Git sends a *name*, such as `refs/heads/dev`.  Their Git now looks to see if they can set this name.  There are two cases:

- They don't have a `refs/heads/dev` branch: it's pretty safe to just create it, so they probably will.  (You can set up fancy rules on the receiving side about what to allow or refuse, hence we can only say "probably" here.)
- They *do* have a `refs/heads/dev`: they'll check to see if changing it from whatever hash it has now, to point to commit `D`, will *keep* all reachable commit objects still reachable.  That's easy to do: is the commit to which their `dev` points now an ancestor of `D`?  If so, the push is OK.  If not, the push gets rejected as a *non-fast-forward*.

Using `git fetch` is almost, but not quite, symmetric.  When you `git fetch` from some other repository, your Git has their Git list *all* their branch names and hash IDs, by default.  Your Git then asks for *all* commits that they have that you don't, along with all their history that they have that you don't.  At the end, though, instead of creating or adjusting local *branch* names, your Git sets up *remote-tracking names* such as `origin/master` and `origin/dev`.

(Technically these are `refs/remotes/origin/master`, in a separate name space form branch names, so that there's no chance of collision.  In practice, as long as you don't name your own branches `origin/whatever` that's not a problem anyway.)

#### The last bit that's the most confusing initially

If your repository is initially created by cloning (which internally does a `git fetch`) some existing repository, you start out with:

```
...--o--...--o   <-- origin/master
      \
       o--...--o   <-- origin/dev
```

and the like.  These remote-tracking names make all the commits reachable, so that they're not all garbage collected.  But then *where does your local branch `master` come from?*

The trick is this: `git checkout` will *create a new local branch name* out by deconstructing the renaming that `git fetch` did with the other Git's branch names.  We know that our `origin/master` must have been their `master`, so `git checkout master`, when we don't *have* a master, will search for `origin/master`.  If that exists, Git just created a *new* label, in the branch name space, giving us:

```
...--o--...--o   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
      \
       o--...--o   <-- origin/dev
```

To create your own new labels, use `git branch <name> <hash-id-or-other-commit-specifier>`, which creates the `refs/heads/<name>` name pointing to the given commit.  You can also use `git checkout -b <name> <specifier>`, which does the name creating *and* immediately does a `git checkout` of the new name to attached `HEAD` to it.

#### Cleanup

There's one more important bit to know, often not covered right away because this graph stuff overwhelms everyone.  This is *refspec* syntax.  Both `git push` and `git fetch` use refspecs, although they treat them differently.

A *refspec* is mostly just a pair of reference names separated by a colon.  The name on the left is the *source* name and the name on the right is the *destination* name.  There's also an optional leading plus sign, which means "force": update the name even if the update is not a fast-forward.

When you use `git fetch origin`, the default refspec is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This means that your Git matches the other Git's branch names (`refs/heads/*`), but turns all those names into your own remote-tracking names (under `refs/remotes/` and furthermore under `origin/`—this leaves room for additional remotes).

If you *omit* the destination name in a `git fetch` command, Git doesn't write any names.  This leaves the fetched commits subject to garbage collection, but there's a delay, because Git first *does* record the hash IDs into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, where you can retrieve them and where they act as temporary retainers.  The `FETCH_HEAD` contents get overwritten by the *next* fetch, so they are not as good as real names in the name-to-ID database.

For `git push`, however, the default is generally to push a branch name to *the same* name on the other Git.  That is, `git push origin master` really means `git push origin master:master` (and Git fills in the `refs/heads/` part when it discovers that `master` is a *branch* name).  For more on how Git looks up these names, see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you type `git push` with no other arguments, the changes will go to the specific remote branch that your local branch tracks. If there is no remote tracking branch, then nothing will happen and  git will complain to this effect.

*Remote tracking* is just another way of saying "this branch will be kept in sync with remote branch `origin/xzy`". Git will automatically set up this synchronisation when you check out a remote branch using the form `git checkout remotebranchname`. However, if you just create a local branch (as you did) git won't automatically set any remote tracking branch.

So with that context, let's consider your example. You have checked out a remote branch using `git checkout UnnamedBranch` that git *will* automatically set to track `origin/UnnamedBranch`. Then, you've used `git branch SomeUniqueName` to create a new branch off `UnnamedBranch`. Git *will not* automatically set this branch to track any remote branch.

That then answers your question. At this point when you `git push` from `SomeUniqueName`, nothing will happen, and git will complain to you.

Now, if you had for some reason managed to push changes to `origin/UnnamedBranch` from your local `SomeUniqueName` (which is possible, see [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) for other forms), then you can revert that.

```
git checkout UnnamedBranch
git push -f
```

This will reset the remote branch to match your local version of `UnnamedBranch`. Keep in mind this will affect the branch history of anyone who pulled updates from `UnnamedBranch` in between your mistake and you fixing it. Only do this carefully and in consultation with your colleagues.