# Move a commit from one branch to another branch

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have mistakenly done a commit in a wrong branch B. It should be in branch A.

Is there any way I can move the commit from B to A.

Please suggest. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1.- The first thing will be list the commits with :

  ```
  git log --oneline
  ```
- 2.- You must find the commit (from branch B) and select the ID of the commit to change
- 3.- Change the branch

  ```
  git checkout A
  ```
- 4.- And from there you must execute the following commit

  ```
  git cherry-pick c8dc73f
  ```

  *Where `c8dc73f` is the number or ID of the commit that I selected in the second step.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with some explanation of what this does and how it solves the OPs problem.

Comment: @Amy I'm finish

Comment: Nice explanation. All good now. The commit has been copied from B to A. Now my next task is to delete/remove that commit from branch B.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra This commit is the ultime ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cherry-pick:

Let say you have two branch A and B and  mistakenly done a commit in a wrong branch B

Take commit it from the branch B using

```
 git log
```

Got to branch A using

```
git checkout <branch-name> 
git checkout A
```

Now do cherry-pick using:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-id>
```

If you get conflicts resolve it  and do `git add` and then commit.If you want to abort cherry-pick use

```
git cherry-pick --abort
```