# Git: removing previously merged commits from master

Tags: git, version-control

The repository I'm working in uses Git's tagging feature to handle "releases" from our `master` branch.

I've just been asked to remove the commits associated with a previous release from `master`, but also preserve those commits on a different branch should they need to be brought back into `master` in the future.

This is an example of what the release history looks like:

1. release-v3 (most recent)
2. release-v2 (second most recent)
3. release-v1 (third most recent)

where `release-v2` contains the commits that need to be removed from `master`.

Ultimately, I *think* what I want to have happen is:

`master` contains:
1. release-v3
2. release-v1

`preserved-branch` contains the preserved commits:
1. release-v2

I'm not sure how best to proceed with this request. Will I eventually need to `--force` push over the current state of `master`?

Comment: There's a lot going on here, but not a lot of detail. Yes, you will have to do a force push, and before that, probably a rebase.

Comment: Are all the commits squashed? Are the releases tags? Can you show a small sample representation of master? Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628563/2988730 for a sample of how to format your sample.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two ways to go about this.  Each has pros and cons.

So let's draw up a simple approximate current state picture.  I'm inferring, based on your question title, that the work is done on branches and `master` consists of merge commits from those branches.  If so it might look a bit like this:

```
  A -- B    C    D -- E
 /      \  / \  /      \
O ------ M1 - M2 ------ M3 <--(master)
         ^    ^         ^
         v1   v2        v3
```

Now you want to update `master` so that it *doesn't* contain the changes from `C`, but you want to keep those changes around in case you need them in the future.  Note that if changes in `C` overlap with changes in later commits, then every approach will involve some amount of conflict resolution.

**With `rebase`**

One option is to rewrite the history.  That is the option that will involve a `--force` (or, preferably, `--force-with-lease`) push over `master`, and that in turn will require clean-up of everybody's local clones to avoid undoing the rewrite.  Also, doing it is complicated by the presence of merge commits.

The first step is to create the new branch; easiest to do that before anything else is changed.  So check out commit `C`.  You'll need an expression that resolves to commit `C` - the commit ID is the most universal thing you could use, but in our example you could also use something like `master^^2` (the 2nd parent of the 1st parent of the `master` tip commit).

```
git checkout master^^2
git branch v2-archive
```

Now you have

```
              C <--(v2-archive)
             / \
  A -- B    /   \    D -- E
 /      \  /     \  /      \
O ------ M1 ----- M2 ------ M3 <--(master)
         ^        ^         ^
         v1       v2        v3
```

and what's left is to rewrite `master`.  The idea here is to `rebase`, but `rebase` doesn't mix well with merge commits.

You can try to use the `--prseerve-merges` option.  If `M3` (or, more generally, every merge being rewritten) was completed successfully using default merge settings, then this will probably be ok.  The command would look like

```
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto master~2 master^ master
```

where `master~2`, `master^`, and `master` stand in as expressions that resolve to `M1`, `M2`, and `M3` in our example.  If it works, this will leave you with

```
  A -- B    /- D' -- E'
 /      \  /           \
O ------ M1  ---------- M3' <--(master)
         ^ \
         v1 \-- C  <--(v2-archive)
             \   \
              \-- M2 -- D -- E
                  ^  \        \
                  v2  \------- M2 
                               ^
                               v3
```

where `D'` and `E'` are the result of replaying changes from `D` and `E` onto the `v1` commit, and `M3'` merges that back to `master` (essentially a rewrite of `M3`).  Note that all the original commits are still present, and in particular the tags still point where the always pointed.

Now you have to decide what to do about tag `v3`.  Normal convention is that tags don't move.  My advice is to create a new version number and tag `M3'` accordingly.  You might then choose to delete the `v2` and `v3` tags, or just leave them for archival purposes.

If that doesn't go smoothly, the other option (starting back at

```
              C <--(v2-archive)
             / \
  A -- B    /   \    D -- E
 /      \  /     \  /      \
O ------ M1 ----- M2 ------ M3 <--(master)
         ^        ^         ^
         v1       v2        v3
```

again), would be to create a temporary branch at the `E` commit

```
git checkout master^2
git branch temp
```

then rebase the temporary branch

```
git rebase --onto master~2 master^ temp
```

so you have

```
              C <--(v2-archive)
             / \
  A -- B    /   \    D -- E
 /      \  /     \  /      \
O ------ M1 ----- M2 ------ M3 <--(master)
         ^ \      ^         ^
         v1 \     v2        v3
             \
              D' -- E' <--(temp)
```

Next you have to push `master` back to `M1`, and then merge in the `temp` branch

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master~2
git merge temp
git branch -D temp
```

taking care to account for any non-standard merge behaviors that were originally in `M3`.  The end result is basically the same; it's just a more manual way of ensuring the merge is handled correctly.  You still need to decide what to do about the tags, just as before.

Either way, at this point you have completed the rewrite.  `D'`, `E'`, and `M3'` are all untested states of the code, and ideally they should all be validated to be sure they pass automated tests.  Of course `M3'` *must* be re-tested, but if you want debugging tools like `bisect` to work well in the future, then you should also make sure the rewritten intermediate states are "clean".

And then you can do the force push and begin the clean-up.

**With `revert`**

The other option is to use `git revert`.  This keeps the history as it is; so if the real goal is to have the next version of the product exclude `v2` features, this is perhaps fine; but if the actual removal of the changes from history is a literal requirement, this isn't the way.

The big advantage is, no history rewrite means no force push and no recovery from upstream rebase for everyone on the team.  Generally this should be the simpler procedure.  The down-side is, you have to take an extra step to allow for future re-integration of the changes from `v2`.

So we're back at our initial state

```
  A -- B    C    D -- E
 /      \  / \  /      \
O ------ M1 - M2 ------ M3 <--(master)
         ^    ^         ^
         v1   v2        v3
```

Again we put a branch at `C`.

```
git checkout master^^2
git branch v2-archive
```

But then we proceed with

```
git revert -m1 master^
```

Note the `-m1` option; this tells git to undo merge `M2` from the perspective of its "first parent" - i.e. undo the changes from `C`.  (In the example, you could just revert `C` instead of `M2`; but if the reverted branch really has many commits, then reverting the merge is more straightforward.)

So now you have

```
              C <--(v2-archive)
             / \
  A -- B    /   \    D -- E
 /      \  /     \  /      \
O ------ M1 ----- M2 ------ M3 -- !M2 <--(master)
         ^        ^         ^
         v1       v2        v3
```

where `!M2` reverses all the changes that were introduced into `master` by `M2`.  As with the history rewrite, you need to decide how you're going to handle tags.  In this case maybe it's a little more clear why `v2` and `v3` might be best left alone (or just deleted), so you might want to create a new version number for `!M2`.

But now, if you try to merge `v2-archive` into `master`, git will find that everything is already up to date because `C` - the commit you're trying to re-integrate - is already "reachable" from `master` (by parent pointers).  For this reason, the git docs say that reverting a merge means you're *permanently* discarding the changes from the branch; but there is a work-around.

```
git rebase -f v2-archive^ v2-archive
```

This creates a new copy of `C` that's basically identical to `C`, but it's not reachable from `master`

```
              C' <--(v2-archive)
             / 
  A -- B    /- C    D -- E
 /      \  /    \  /      \
O ------ M1 ---- M2 ------ M3 -- !M2 <--(master)
         ^       ^         ^
         v1      v2        v3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create reverse commits from the commits from release 2 and check them in to master.

This would give you a chance to explain what is happening (what changes you are reversing).

This also avoids rewriting history and `--forcing` anything.