# Move Commits from One Branch to Another Branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, branch, github-pages

I've got two branches on a repo in GitHub; one is the default branch `master`, and the other is called `gh-pages`. I set the default branch to be `gh-pages` on GitHub.

I use VS Code Editor to code my project (`coder-in-pink`), so I created a new branch named `gh-pages` in VS Code, and I committed my saved work in the source control.

I'm not allowed to embed pictures in my posts yet, so here's [the little picture of the gh-pages branch I set in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b96h.png). (It might not be very helpful, though.)

But today I found out that it had been committed to the `master` branch. How do I move/transfer it to the `gh-pages` branch?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm planning to make the website with HTTPS and a custom domain afterwards, which is why I want to use the `gh-pages` branch.

Here's the link to my repo on GitHub => [Coder In Pink](https://github.com/cate-k/coder-in-pink).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: @RobinGreen, I think the answers tymtam and sublimegeek gave are a bit more helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout gh-pages` This makes sure you're on the `gh-pages` branch

`git merge master` This merges master *into* gh-pages

Finally
`git push origin gh-pages` This will push your changes back to GitHub.  Origin isn't needed, but this is the long-form way of doing it.

The short way is just `git push` while being checked out on `gh-pages`

Comment: Thank you, @sublimegeek!

Comment: If I could mark @tymtam's answer and your answer as the answers that worked, I would.

Comment: I appreciate it.  Glad it worked.  Reach out if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do

1. Merge `master` to `gh-pages` - this would bring the commit to `gh-pages`.
2. Revert the commit in `master`, if needed, by `git revert commit-id`.

---

#### Update

I found this by coincidence.

The GitHub Blog's [How to undo (almost) anything with Git](https://blog.github.com/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/) has a section that matches your scenario.

> ### *Once more, with branching*
>
> **Scenario**: You made some commits, then realized you were checked out on master. You wish you could make those commits on a feature branch instead.
>
> (...)

Comment: Okay, let me look into that first.

Comment: I've never done a merge before, so I'm looking it up on the web.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to merge the branches? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I think it's best if you refer to a tutorial. There is just not enough space here to explain it :) Here's an official one. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging Good luck!

Comment: Here's another one, also with pictures: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge

Comment: Thanks, @tymtam! Your tips have been really helpful.