# Shuffling committed changes between git branches and then deleting them on the source

Tags: git

**Please note:** I *understand* my question is *very similar* to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git) -- **however** there IS a slight difference! Please ready this question in its entirety!

---

New to git, I made a bunch of changes on my project's `develop` branch, whereas it seems I should have cut a feature branch off of `develop` first and made my changes there. I have already added (`git add .`) and committed (`git commit -m "blah"`) my changes but I have **not** pushed them yet.

I'm hoping there is a way to:

1. Create a new branch off of my local `develop` and move my changes over to it
2. Reset my local `develop` so that its as if I never made changes to `develop` in the first place

From the question I referenced above, it seems that the correct solution is something like this:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git merge develop
git checkout develop
git reset --hard HEAD~X # Go back X commits
git checkout newbranch
```

#### Here's how my question is different than the one I mentioned:

The problem is: this is a very active project and MANY (30+) commits by MANY other developers have transpired since I started making my local changes.

**So I'm note sure what the real value of `HEAD~X` needs to be!**

Ideally, I'd like to just say: "*Hey `git`, whatever is the latest on the remote `develop`, yeah, set my local `develop` to that commit and completely blow out/erase any of my committed changes to it.*"

**Is this possible to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Just create a new branch from the current point in your local `develop` branch, then reset off the commits you added:

```
# from develop
git branch newbranch
git reset --hard HEAD~1   # assuming you only made one commit
```

Replace the `1` in `HEAD~1` with however many commits you did actually make to `develop` before realizing that your work belonged in its own branch.