# stage files in git in vscode and then changes cancaled

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm new to git
I was working on a project and i wanted to stage my work in another branch ,
so i created another branch with

```
$ git branch <name>
```

and then

```
$ git checkout <name>
```

and try to stage it again but then the changes got cancled or removed or something.
I'm not sure how to watch the last work that i made , if it's not earesed somehow .
when i try to checked my former branch i was working on VSCode pops up a message:
[image]

Maybe it's a noob question but i don't want to lose my work .
I hope i was clear enough on this , because i'm fairly new to git .

thanks.

Comment: Yes, you first need to either commit your changes or squash them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)