# Move commits into new branch with merge commits

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

I have a linear history like so

```
----a--b--c--d--e--f----    main
```

I want to move a series of commits into a new branch and create a merge commit into the old branch, creating a non-linear history like so

```
----a-------x--d'--e'--f'-- main
      \    /
       b--c
```

where `x` is the new merge commit.

How do I do this?

Note, the moved commits aren't the most recent ones (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by creating a few pointers to make things easier.

```
git branch base <a>
git branch feat <c>
```

The diagram looks like this.

```
----a--b--c--d--e--f----    main
    ^     ^
  base  feat
```

Now we merge `feat` into `base`, creating the merge commit.

```
git switch base
git merge --no-ff feat
```

The diagram now looks like this.

```
----a------x          base
     \    /
      b--c--d--e--f-- main
```

Now we rebase `main` onto `base`, moving it onto the new merge commit.

```
git switch main
git rebase --onto base feat
```

Finally, we can clean up the pointers, which we don't need anymore.

```
git branch -d base
git branch -d feat
```

And we end up with the diagram that looks like this.

```
----a------x--d'--e'--f'-- main
     \    /
      b--c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily enough, but you will be rewriting the history of `main` which is not recommended and might have to be force-pushed to the remote.

Anyway, here's your initial situation, more or less (I'm using `master` instead of `main` and I only went up to `e`):

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
* d5de97b (HEAD -> master) e
* 97f47d1 d
* 7c33da9 c
* 295b3c7 b
* 18622aa a
```

OK, I propose to turn `b` and `c` into commits on a branch `feature` that will be merged into `master` before `d`. Ready? (Some of these steps, such as some of the `checkout` moves, may be unnecessary, but I didn't pause to worry about that.)

```
$ git branch holdmyplace        # prevent losing any commits
$ git branch feature 7c33da9    # call `c` by a branch name `feature`
$ git reset --hard 18622        # slide `master` all the way back to `a`...
$ git merge --no-ff feature     # ...and merge `feature` with a merge commit!
$ git checkout holdmyplace      # okay, now return to the placeholder branch...
$ git rebase --onto master feature holdmyplace 
                                # ...and append it to `master`
$ git checkout master           # finally, return to master...
$ git reset --hard holdmyplace  # ...and slide it back up to the end!
$ git branch -d holdmyplace     # we no longer need the placeholder branch
```

And now we have:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
* 0d58dd1 (HEAD -> master) e
* 7831073 d
*   2bd7688 Merge branch 'feature'
|\  
| * 7c33da9 (feature) c
| * 295b3c7 b
|/  
* 18622aa a
```

Which is what you said you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

```
git checkout a
git merge --no-ff c
git cherry-pick c..main
# at this point you are on a revision that has a history like what you asked for
# now it's time to move main
git branch -f main
git checkout main
```

And if you have pushed that branch into other repos, you will have to force-push new because you rewrote its history. (there are other considerations out of you rewriting history, just in case).