# Move commit (already pushed) from branchA to new branchB

Tags: git

I was working on branch `feature1` and accidentally made a new branch `feature2` without switching back to `master` first. Then I added a commit and pushed it to GitHub.

Now a PR that I submitted based on `feature2` includes commit `D`, which it shouldn't.

I want to move `feature2` so it's a direct descendant of `master` and no longer includes commit `D`.

To illustrate, I want to turn this:

```
┌─────────────┐     ┌─────┐    ┌─────┐    ┌─────┐                   
│   master    │────▶│  A  │───▶│  B  │───▶│  C  │                   
└─────────────┘     └─────┘    └─────┘    └─────┘                   
       ╲                                                            
        ╲        ┌───────────┐    ┌─────┐                           
         ╲──────▶│ feature1  │───▶│  D  │                           
                 └───────────┘    └─────┘                           
                                     ╲                              
                                      ╲     ┌───────────┐    ┌─────┐
                                       ╲───▶│ feature2  │───▶│  E  │
                                            └───────────┘    └─────┘
```

To this:

```
                                            ┌───────────┐    ┌─────┐
             ╱─────────────────────────────▶│ feature2  │───▶│  E  │
            ╱                               └───────────┘    └─────┘
           ╱                                                        
┌─────────────┐     ┌─────┐    ┌─────┐    ┌─────┐                   
│   master    │────▶│  A  │───▶│  B  │───▶│  C  │                   
└─────────────┘     └─────┘    └─────┘    └─────┘                   
       ╲                                                            
        ╲        ┌───────────┐     ┌─────┐                          
         ╲──────▶│ feature1  │────▶│  D  │                          
                 └───────────┘     └─────┘
```

I read [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git/). I'm sure the answer is in there somewhere, but among the dozens of replies I couldn't find one that seemed accurate and safe for this case.

Comment: As a brief aside, your diagrams are a bit confusing due to the convention you've chosen - usually branch names are diagrammed as coming after commits, since they typically stay pointing to the last commit on their branch. It was unclear that D is supposed to be part of feature1, as opposed to a disconnected commit that comes after feature1's commit(s).

Comment: @Amber Thanks for your comment & answer. Can you point me to a canonical drawing that conforms to the standard? Sorry if this was confusing.

Comment: The exact use case and diagrams here are also in the documentation for `git rebase`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

- `--onto master` says you want to wind up with the result being based on top of `master`
- `feature1` is the branch that's included that you don't want to be included
- `feature2` is the branch you're wanting to update / separate

Comment: Which branch should be checked out when this command is executed?

Comment: @luckman212 It doesn't matter.

Comment: @TTT That isn't actually what I mean. I mean what I said. When you use the full three parameter version of rebase onto, it makes no difference where you are to begin with. The same thing will happen, regardless.

Comment: @matt sorry, comment deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you want to do something like this:

1. Create a new branch based on the latest `master`.
2. Cherry-pick all of the commits that are only on `feature2` onto your new branch.
3. Rename your new branch to `feature2`.

You could actually do exactly that and get what you want. There is also a one-line rebase command for doing the same thing which is described in [Amber's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72155068/184546)

The only tweak I would consider is to fetch first, and then use `origin/master` instead of `master`. This is so you don't have to worry about whether your local copy of `master` is up to date. Every time you `git fetch`, you update all of your remote tracking branches, such as `origin/master`. Then you can use `origin/master` any place you previous would have used `master`, without having to ever update `master` again. In fact, I'd recommend you delete your local copy of `master` and just use `origin/master` instead from now on! You started this off because you:

> accidentally made a new branch `feature2` without switching back to `master` first.

Note even if you do switch to `master` first, you still need to remember to pull it to update it. If you don't have a copy of `master` at all, from now on you can always use this method to create a new branch off of the latest `master`:

```
git fetch
git switch -c new-branch origin/master --no-track
```

Now your new branch will always be created with the latest `master` from the remote, which is almost always preferred in a Pull Request workflow.