# Git, tracking wrong remote branch after moving commits between branches

Tags: git, version-control

I needed to move some commits to another, new branch, and I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463546/4537160).
So, as mentioned in the linked question, I went from:

```
old_branch A - B - C - D - E
```

to this

```
new_branch       C - D - E
                /
old_branch A - B
```

The problem is that now, if I make changes and try to run "git push" from new_branch, I'm getting the error:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push . HEAD:old_branch

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push . HEAD
```

I tried running:

```
git remote show origin
```

and I got

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: xxx.git
  Push  URL: xxx.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    new_branch                         tracked
    old_branch                         tracked
    master                             tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    old_branch                         merges with remote old_branch
    master                             merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    new_branch                         pushes to new_branch (up to date)
    old_branch                         pushes to old_branch (up to date)
    master                             pushes to master     (up to date)
```

If I try checking:

```
git status
```

I got:

```
On branch new_branch
Your branch and 'old_branch' have diverged,
and have 6 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

I can push the code to the new_branch by using git gui, but how can I fix this so that I can git push as well?

Comment: Note that you currently have a (local) branch name set as the upstream of some other (local) branch name. This is a valid thing to do in Git! It's just pretty rare for anyone to *want* to do it. As [LeGEC answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72939559/1256452), the cure is to tell Git that this is the wrong upstream—that `new_branch` should have a different upstream set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you display : your local `new_branch` branch is not tracking the branch you expect.

Set the correct remote tracking branch for your local `new_branch` branch :

```
git branch -u origin/new_branch new_branch
```

---

note that this upstream branch is only used to provide a default value when you run `git push` with no extra argument.

You can always explicitly name the remote branch you want to push to :

```
git push origin new_branch:new_branch

# could also be :
git push origin new_branch:any_branch
git push origin new_branch:refs/tags/any_tag
```

You can also update the tracked branch while running a git push :

```
git push -u origin new_branch:new_branch
```