# Untangle two lines with `git add -p`

Tags: git, git-add

I've got a file with the following changes:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -280,6 +281,7 @@
 if( foo )
 {
     bla();
-    test( true );
+    removeThis();
+    test( false );
 }
 else
```

How can I commit the change for `test()` only, and avoid committing removeThis() ?
Each time I try to edit the hunk manually git tells me it does not apply cleanly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> How can I commit the change for test() only, and avoid committing removeThis() ?

That's simple.

1. Enter `add -i` mode, then select `5: [p]atch` by pressing <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Choose your file by entering its number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start editing patches.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit your hunk (you seem to have succesfully reached here by doing `git add -p` instead).
4. Delete the line with `removeThis()` **completely**, with `+` sign at the beginning as well.  Do not touch anything else!  The resultant text should look like a patch for the change you're committing.
5. **Save** the file and **exit** the editor.

The patch will apply well.  I've just checked.  Check again too--maybe it's another hunk that doesn't apply?

Other than that, your `,` symbols near the `+`/`-` look suspicious.  Perhaps, your `patch` and `diff` programs are somehow out of sync?  Try removing the `,`s from the hunk as well.

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out my editor (`notepad2`) saved the file in LF line endings. Saving them in LRLF endings fixed the final problem.

Comment: FYI, the comma's in front of the lines are typo's typing the post here, they are not in the source. Fixed them.

Comment: @vdboor Just curious, why the LF-to-CRLF solves? Are you on Windows platform?

Comment: @Iceberg: I used to be for the job I was in, but not anymore.

Comment: Pavel, the key to your answer was "The resultant text should look like a patch for the change you're committing." Easy to remember, and that's the part it's hard to remember, not "Press e to edit your hunk". :)