# Better Version Control (Distributed) - Minimum impact on sources - always possible to update

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bazaar

I am f...fed up with Subversion.  Need a version control that:

1. Can be used without affecting the sources with embedded files (like the Subversion .svn-directories), or having to check in and then check out (If you want to version control live web-site files for example).
2. It should always be possible to bring the repository quickly up to date whatever I have done (Without resolving conflicts or adding files first etc.)
3. Ideally it should be possible to merge repositories starting out as separate.

I thing it should be a distributed one, I think GIT is the *Lingua Franca*, but there is also Mercurial and Bazaar, which should have some advantages since they exist :-)

---

*+1*
Apart from the 3 points the main criteria is what is best for a software developer to know and use:-)

---

*+2*
An example regarding poin 2.: In Drupal I might move directory-structures around, delete some structures, add some 3d party.  Ideally the repository should store exactly what has happened, but sometimes I just want to have a snapshot of the actual structure in the repository without spending time on it.  (In an ideal SCM-system you would be able to fill in the details later).

Comment: What is your question? Do you need a comparison between Git and Hg? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git

Comment: ...and here: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/how-did-we-get-here.html#id343252 ... and here: http://whygitisbetterthanx.com ... and here: http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/why-switch-to-bazaar.html

Comment: I'm a huge DVCS booster, but it really sounds like the people below suggesting git or mercurial are missing Olav's point.  He wants to not have to add/remove files and both require it (though it's easy).  He wants to never merge (whereas both do it freqeuently).  He wants to never have to check-in/checkout-files, which is the principal action of both systems.

Olav, perhaps you should look into something like dropbox, rdiff-backup, or a regular bi-directional rsync job.  What you're describing isn't version control it's a deployment tool.

Comment: I want to check in/out, add/remove! - - -

The point is I don't want to be FORCED to tell the source control what is going on WHEN all I really need is a snapshot of my directory structure.

Comment: You need a snapshot of your dir structure for what? You want the last commited (clean) or the edited (dirty) directory? You need your local or remote directory? You want the VC to automatically add new files?

Comment: "Snapshots" are really the main point of SCM.

Comment: Say I move a directory in Drupal, the main thing is to get the current state of my directories into the repository.  It is nice to have the information about what has actually happened, but its often not worth the time on a Friday Night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just answer for bazaar:

1. One .bzr-directory in the root, just like git. Additionally there's a optional .bzrignore-file at the root which contains the list of ignored directories/files.
2. Well when you update/pull there are potentially some conflicts. Howere you can shelve your changes if you want before a update/pull. This will basically shelve up all your changes. Then you update/pull and you have your working directory in latest version.
3. Yes, you can do that. There's a special ['join'-command](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.1/en/user-reference/join-help.html?highlight=join). This command will integrate the another branch and will keep the full history of both.

I think in the end all three, Git, Mercurial and Bazaar, will do the job. These three version control systems a very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just talking about git:

1. one .git directory in the root.
2. git stash, git pull, git stash pop (if this is what you want)
3. [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: You could just fetch and not merge, or do all your code on something other than master

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial does all 3 points. It does have a .hg directory in the root directory though.