# syncing project between pc and laptop

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app on my Windows 7 Home PC using Eclipse.   I have just bought a laptop and would like to be able to take my project with me on the laptop.   I have installed Eclipse and the Android SDK etc on the laptop and using a usb memory stick carried the project folders over to the laptop.   I then used import to install my project into the laptop Eclipse environment.   So far so good.   Now if I make changes on my PC what would be the simplest way to update the project on the laptop.  I have read on here about git etc but don't want to get into that complexity just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dropbox would be an option and it would definitely be kind of easy.

But I think you should simply use a [Revision Control System](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/version-control/info) like [GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) (there are a lot more). You might be a little bit more difficult than using Dropbox in the beginning but it will be more comfortable than Dropbox after a short while.

Git has the advantage that it is a distributed revision control system (no server required).

You might want to have a look at these questions:

- [What is the Difference Between Mercurial and Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git)
- [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

and here are many more:

- [Highest Voted 'version-control' Questions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control?sort=votes)

Comment: I decided to opt for a Revision Control System and downloaded EGit as a plugin to my Eclipse.   Thhat has installed ok and the project I am working on is now included in a repository.   I prefer the GUI but am still struggling with the original aim which is to sync versions on my PC and laptop.  If I make a change to the PC version I want to bring the laptop into line.  I am not sure which of the options on the 'Team' menu is designed to do this.   There is one option 'Synchronize' but I'm not sure what to do after clicking this.   Do I need to download EGit on the laptop as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think may be not the simpliest but most correct way is to use some source control system DCVS such as Git or Mercurial might be the best choise since they don't require central server storage. Not only this will let you to sync between different development machines but also keep history of your changes.

Comment: Well if you have open source project and you are the only developer you can still use svn and googlecode. Offcourse GitHub is better  but if it's you first source control I find it easier to understand SVN. Netherless Git and Mercurial are tools of choice for me =)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use Dropbox - http://www.dropbox.com/. It will automatically sync files between various computers.

Comment: dropbox is definitely easy. but i would recommend a Revision Control System in this case.

Comment: I know, but he seems to be averse to trying VCS immediately. Hence my suggestion. Once he is more comfortable with development, he should probably start experimenting with a simple VCS like SVN.

Comment: sure your right :) but i just wanted to point out that Dropbox is solution but should not not be considered a 'good one'.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you look into [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), it is similar to Git however I find it slightly easier to use and it has better Windows support. Then sign up for a [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) account which is free and will let you sync your code from anywhere.

Whilst I realise that version control might seem a little daunting at first getting used to it will quickly pay dividends. You will get into a right nightmare of what was that change I made last night that broke everything? And keeping tonnes of copies of the code in seperate for each time you make a small change. Version control makes all this nice and easy to handle and is a great habit to get into early.

Comment: However, if you are super determined to not use version control, I would second Sparkymat's answer of using Dropbox.