# What version control use if I'm the only developer?

Tags: version-control

I want to use some version control for my projects, but I'm the only developer, there is not others. I want to use my pendrive like repository because I develop in many different places(but the same project).

I only worked with SVN, but in that case, was not good, I think an DVCS was better.

But now, I really don't know what to use, if SVN is the best option. I've looked for another solutions like Mercurial, Git, and Fossil, but I don't understand the differences, and mainly, if they are the best options for my situation.

I need to know what is best in this case.

Comment: Get is free and good.  Seems like a good candidate.

Comment: If you want to work from many different places then a system which requires a central server might not be a good solution. Anything else is more a matter of personal preference. Try some and choose the one you like most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're the only developer, then the best version control is the one that you are most comfortable with.  The goal of version control is to make your life as a developer easier and safer, so there's no point in fighting with a version control that you don't know.

However, if you want to learn how to use a new version control system, this is a great opportunity.

If you think that you're going to have more developers working on this project later, then you want to think about a robust solution like SVN.

Comment: I tried learn Git and Mercurial, but at the moment, I get SVN again because is what I know. In my next project, I will try to learn something new.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição - I had also that feeling, but when I gave GIT a second chance, I understood why it may be better than SVN in many cases.

Comment: @Nicolás Yes, I will give another chance, now now because the time is running, but surely in the next time I will give a chance to it.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely recommend Git. It is a little cryptic at times, but it seems to be/become the de-facto standard for most open source projects. It's very powerful and it'll enable you to work with the great service that is Github :)

Answer (score 2):

There are good topics on SO that compare Git, Mercurial, svn, etc.
[What is the Difference Between Mercurial and Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git)

To me an important requirement was easy, free, private repositories online so I started to use http://Bitbucket.org  They support both Mercurial and Git.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @dudemonkey sentences. Except last - tastes can differ. Even as sole developer, you can (and have) use best techniques - i.e you may have non-linear development (thus - branching|merging), refactoring of code, different targets. Try and select best for you solution.

Nobody mentioned Fossil SCM - small, portable app in one exe, with all basic features of DVCS, integrated Wiki and tickets - which you can have (with repo) in USB, for example for max mobility

Answer (score 1):

In first place stay away from SVN or any other CVCS, they suck. To learn more about DVCS, I recommend the Eric Sink's Book, it's free: http://www.ericsink.com/vcbe/

As you plan to work on different machines, the best solution would be to have an online repository, I think it's more pratical and safer than the pendrive. Some of the most known out there are: https://bitbucket.org/, https://github.com/, https://launchpad.net/, http://code.google.com/projecthosting/. Remember that with a DVCS you don't need to be online all the time, you can commit locally and push to the server later. If your project is not open source, you should stick with BitBucket as it's the only one that offers free hosting for closed source projects.

If you really want to work just in the pendrive, don't leave the repository just in the pendrive. It's safer to clone the repository from the pen drive to the machines you will work. Then you Push/Pull to the pen drive's repository to synchronize.