# Mercurial in Aptana terminal

Tags: mercurial, aptana

Hello I like to use Mercurial in Aptana. 
How easy is it to run Mercurial or DOS in the terminal of Aptana?

Do I only need to edit a configure file that contact the path of Tortoisehg Mercurial or are there more steps to take?

I know the basics for Mercurial to create, clone push and named branche.
Because I am just starting to use version control I like to make a decide to use Mercurial or 
Git.
If the configuration is easy to do I like to use Mercurial but if there are more steps to it maybe it is easier to learn Git.

Answer (score 1):

Since Aptana is based on Eclipse, you can probably install the [HGEclipse](http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE) plugin and use Mercurial directly in the IDE instead of using the terminal.

Concerning the Terminal, I never used Aptana and it's been a long time since I used Eclipse, but I think the only requirement is that Mercurial (the `hg` binary) is in your path. You can probably do that in the Aptana configuration or your operating system global path variable.

If you still must decide between using Git or Mercurial, I won't use the ease of configuration in Aptana to do my choice. There's many more to a VCS than the fact you're able to set up it's use easily for the Aptana terminal.

You should really choose based on the feature, learning curve and your needs :) A good start is maybe this SO question : [What is the Difference Between Mercurial and Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git)

In short : Git is more powerful but Mercurial is easier to use.