# the difference between Git and Mercurial

Tags: repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Difference Between Mercurial and Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git)

I'm new to DVC systems and I've registered on [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/).

Do I need to use Git and Mercurial systems together or I can use one of them, and what is the difference?

thank You for help

Comment: Git vs Mercurial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git

Comment: I'm too lazy to make a good answer, but it will end up with "go with Git" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are separate DVCS. I would choose Git over Mecurial, since its popularity is greater.