# forking and project management functions on bitbucket

Tags: github, repository, bitbucket

ı m trying to git my codes from eclipse to  bitbucket first of all I decided to create a private repository but it is asking me about forking

> -allow forks
>
> -allow only private forks
>
> -no forks

also what is the difference among git and mercurial type of repositories.

moewover we have an  button group that named project management and  offers us alternatives issue tracking and wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -allow forks
>
> -allow only private forks
>
> -no forks

These three options are only available for *private repos*.

- **Allow forks** means it both support public forks (the fork version can be seen publicly) and private forks (the fork version can only seen by the person who forked it).
- **Allow only private forks** means it allow private-only forks.
- **No forks** means you repo don't allow any fork.

And fundamentally, to **fork** a project (take the source from someone's repository at certain point in time, and apply your own diverging changes to it), you would clone the remote repository to create a copy of it, then do your own work in your local repository and commit changes.

---

For differences between git and mercurial type of repositories, you can check out this post: [What is the Difference Between Mercurial and Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git)

Comment: actually what ıs fork ?

Comment: actually what is fork

Comment: I came here because I was hoping for an answer to: _How private is a "private repo" if it can be forked privately?_ I guess/hope that there must be some mechanism to control the possibility of private forks in more detail. For instance: Will I be asked before someone can fork privately? Would be nice to extend the answer in this direction.